# How do I get a list of locally installed Python modules?

Tags: python, module, pip

How do I get a list of Python modules installed on my computer?

Comment: you can just do >>>help() and then >>>modules

Comment: Is there an alternative?  help() hangs for me.

Comment: A lot of these answers assume you have access to a command line. If you are using AWS Lambda, you have to do it all from inside Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54939905/117471

Comment: What is wrong with `pip list`?

Comment: Adding this oneliner from Julius Naeumann comment: `python3 -c "help('modules')"`

Comment: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-list-installed-python-packages/

Comment: For the mysterious directory "site-packages" mentioned in some answers, see *[What is Python's site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory)*. [Sample location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory#comment75452894_31384640): `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Answer (score 664, accepted):

### Solution

## Do not use with pip > 10.0!

My 50 cents for getting a `pip freeze`-like list from a Python script:

```python
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

As a (too long) one liner:

```python
sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
```

Giving:

```
['behave==1.2.4', 'enum34==1.0', 'flask==0.10.1', 'itsdangerous==0.24',
 'jinja2==2.7.2', 'jsonschema==2.3.0', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'nose==1.3.3',
 'parse-type==0.3.4', 'parse==1.6.4', 'prettytable==0.7.2', 'requests==2.3.0',
 'six==1.6.1', 'vioozer-metadata==0.1', 'vioozer-users-server==0.1',
 'werkzeug==0.9.4']
```

### Scope

This solution applies to the system scope or to a virtual environment scope, and covers packages installed by `setuptools`, `pip` and ([god forbid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)) `easy_install`.

### My use case

I added the result of this call to my Flask server, so when I call it with `http://example.com/exampleServer/environment` I get the list of packages installed on the server's virtualenv. It makes debugging a whole lot easier.

### Caveats

I have noticed a strange behaviour of this technique - when the Python interpreter is invoked in the same directory as a `setup.py` file, it does not list the package installed by `setup.py`.

#### Steps to reproduce:

##### Create a virtual environment

```
$ cd /tmp
$ virtualenv test_env
New python executable in test_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ source test_env/bin/activate
(test_env) $
```

##### Clone a Git repository with `setup.py`

```
(test_env) $ git clone https://github.com/behave/behave.git
Cloning into 'behave'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 4350, done.
remote: Total 4350 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4350/4350), 1.85 MiB | 418.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2388/2388), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

We have behave's `setup.py` in `/tmp/behave`:

```
(test_env) $ ls /tmp/behave/setup.py
    /tmp/behave/setup.py
```

##### Install the Python package from the Git repository

```
(test_env) $ cd /tmp/behave && pip install .
running install
...
Installed /private/tmp/test_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.0-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for behave==1.2.5a1
```

#### If we run the aforementioned solution from `/tmp`

```
>>> import pip
>>> sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
['behave==1.2.5a1', 'enum34==1.0', 'parse-type==0.3.4', 'parse==1.6.4', 'six==1.6.1']
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/private/tmp'
```

#### If we run the aforementioned solution from `/tmp/behave`

```
>>> import pip
>>> sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
['enum34==1.0', 'parse-type==0.3.4', 'parse==1.6.4', 'six==1.6.1']
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/private/tmp/behave'
```

`behave==1.2.5a1` is missing from the second example, because the working directory contains `behave`'s `setup.py` file.

I could not find any reference to this issue in the documentation. Perhaps I shall open a bug for it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I think it better answers the question because I ask "locally" installed Python modules. Pip freeze is also not always the way to go. This works better - I think.

Comment: `pkgutil.iter_modules()` works (see @Johnysweb's answer); this pip solution above doesn't list all packages, just the ones installed via pip

Comment: @metaperture `pip.get_installed_distributions()` displays packages installed by `pip`, `easy_install`, and `setuptools` (`python setup.py install`). The only exception - not sure if it's a bug - is that it does not show a package if it's called in the same directory of its `setup.py`.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this new answer because it works in the entire system or a virtual environment. Johnsyweb mentions some useful points, but I still see that this answer is better in the entire system or virtual. Please, provide me examples if Johnsyweb or any other answer is better than this.

Comment: Please, let me know if you understand this better" I have noticed a strange behaviour of this technique - when the Python interpreter is invoked in the same directory as a setup.py file, it does not list the package installed by setup.py". It may be related to same issues which I have had in different runtimes and warmup situations.

Comment: @Masi Thanks for the bounty. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: @Masi Just added a detailed explanation of the caveat of this solution. It is indeed a strange one.

Comment: @AdamMatan Just open a bug for it so we get better understanding in it.

Comment: @AdamMatan Actually, if you're using multiple python installs with site-packages in several directories, this will fail. It works assuming all your installs have been registered on the same python instance (via pip/easy_install/setuptools) but fails if you've modified your python path to include other installs (or custom libraries). For a normal workflow, this is probably fine, but it may not be robust.

Comment: @metaperture Interesting - I did not think of that scenario. Does it mean that there can be a package that's available to the calling script, but will not be listed?

Comment: @AdamMatan yes, entire directories can be added manually to $PYTHONPATH (or equivalently sys.path) and this method will never notice them. In a clean setup, this probably won't happen, but my work has severe permissions restrictions so many of us run on a mashup of "canonical environment" with proprietary libs and "custom environment" where we have complete permissions. When I tested your method on either environment packages from the other didn't show up.

Comment: There must be a workaround for this. @AdamMatan Have you thought about it? I think the PYTHONPATH should be included somewhere. Checking it first, and then doing similar thing as you do here.

Comment: Filed bug upstream at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3091, copying the bugs.python.org issue above

Comment: missed "import pip; " before one-liner in second code sample :)

Comment: @DenisBarmenkov Right, and the `print` command is also missing. I figured out it would be clear from context.

Comment: `print '\n'.join(installed_packages_list)` gave a prettier, easier to read list in 2.7

Comment: An alternative:
`import pkg_resources; installed_packages = [(d.project_name, d.version) for d in pkg_resources.working_set]`

Comment: The import can go on the front, like so: import pip;sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])

Comment: My next goal is to figure out how to format the listing with one item per line.

Comment: Improving on the excellent one-line script posted by @Adam Matan, I made  an improved script that iterates the sequence returned by sorted, yielding a much more digestible listing. The script, ListInstalledPackages.py, is at https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/personal/dagray_p6lists_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=184919bbb2a214b33956de3a1b5b53a0b&authkey=ATSPl5golpQ0yRjf1tuaC2I, along with sample output at https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/personal/dagray_p6lists_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=130e554b3388645cca5b2f9da1ad157f9&authkey=Aeeat2w1ZTLZmYrymDCuAsA.

Comment: Since I'm still new to writing in Python, the script that I just mentioned is a bit more than one line (10 altogether, 3 providing the core functionality, to which the other 7 add some beautification.  Even so, it's one line from a shell, since you have only to invoke the script, and pipe its output to a file.

Comment: As of pip 10, this answer will no longer work. The comment from @ebolyen shows alternative commands that do work.  I came to the same conclusion and posted the complete revised code below.

Comment: In recent versions of pip, this won't work, yielding an error message saying `AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'`.

Comment: I want to run your code. But I received this error: AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'

Comment: No. This is not recommended, see here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Comment: @ebolyen what about system packages? (like os) They do not show up with your method. Any ideas about how to integrate them in the result?

Answer (score 1264):

```
help('modules')
```

in a Python shell/prompt.

Comment: I get such a warning: FutureWarning: apt API not stable yet
  warnings.warn("apt API not stable yet", FutureWarning). I did not get a list of Python modules. I am using Python 2.5.

Comment: Could you paste the entire warning at for example http://paste.pocoo.org and post the link here?

Comment: “/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/apt/__init__.py:18: FutureWarning: apt API not stable yet” is normal on Debian/Ubuntu Pythons, an artefact of attempting to graft apt packages into Python package management. I still see the (textual) list of modules.

Comment: @dF `pydoc modules` works. You should submit it as an answer.

Comment: @dF: pydoc modules, gives me the exactly same output as in python shell: help('modules')

Comment: @Masi: matplotlib related problem according to http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=519965 Should be fixed in the latest version available from http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/
@Abizern: pydoc modules and help('modules') do the same thing...

Comment: @ChristopheD: How can I see the version of my matplotlib? I tried import matplotlib; matplotlib --version unsuccessfully.

Comment: WARNING: This killed my window manager (Ubuntu/Compiz) for some reason.

Comment: nobar, zanbri, @Joe Frambach: on Ubuntu? There's a bug described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836

Comment: FYI , the Ubuntu segfault bug per @ChristopheD is still unassigned.

Comment: how can i get extra info about where the modules are installed and what is the current version?

Comment: With Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu Linux 10 this only works with root privileges (sudo pydoc modules).  On my system it also tries to configure the output for speech synthesis, so answer "no" to the first two questions and a few seconds later it lists all the installed modules by name-only in a four-column format.

Comment: `python -c 'help("modules")'`

Comment: It seems this does not show modules installed via namespace packages. (while e.g. pip list does)

Comment: for python 2.7+ or maybe for python 3.7+ as well (use double quotes outside): python -c "help('modules')"

Comment: thx @Pranjay: using `python -c 'help("modules")'` did strange stuff, like executing my nagstamon O.o - BUT - using `python -c "help('modules')" ` (interchanged qutoing) worked smoothly!

Answer (score 348):

Now, these methods I tried myself, and I got exactly what was advertised:  All the modules.

Alas, really you don't care much about the stdlib. You know what you get with a Python install.

Really, I want the stuff that *I* installed.

What actually, surprisingly, worked just fine was:

```
pip freeze
```

Which returned:

```
Fabric==0.9.3
apache-libcloud==0.4.0
bzr==2.3b4
distribute==0.6.14
docutils==0.7
greenlet==0.3.1
ipython==0.10.1
iterpipes==0.4
libxml2-python==2.6.21
```

I say "surprisingly", because the package install tool is the exact place one would expect to find this functionality, although not under the name 'freeze', but Python packaging is so weird that I am flabbergasted that this tool makes sense.  Pip 0.8.2 and Python 2.7.

Comment: I guess the idea behind the name is that you get a "frozen" snapshot of what is installed right now, which you can later feed back into pip to get exactly the same modules installed in a different environment.

Comment: Arash, you can install pip in Windows too! First install setuptools and then use easy_install to install pip :)

Comment: This is excellent, but it seems to miss some of the libraries I installed. For example, it doesn't list PyQt.

Comment: Starting from pip 1.3 there's the [list](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-list) command.

Comment: it works. What a mess python is. Why can they not get their act together and come up with solutions similar to what exists in Rails? (Gemfile, bundler, rvm)

Comment: Note that even if you didn't install your packages using pip, pip will still be able to list most of your modules along with their versions, which is great! An alternative script I made: https://gist.github.com/lrq3000/6175522

Comment: Also you can get the same result as "pip freeze" in a Python shell using: pip.get_installed_distributions()

Comment: @Dimitris rvm only works on Linux, and it's not as flexible as virtualenv. You can now distribute packages using source distributions or wheels. pip can create a bundle of packages, if you really want. It took some time to sort everything out, but Python *has* it's act together now, and better than Ruby.

Comment: Actually, this does NOT return a complete list of installed modules on my system, although I can't tell if it's related to the version of pip being used (I'm running pip 10).

Answer (score 156):

Since pip version 1.3, you've got access to:

```
pip list
```

Which seems to be syntactic sugar for "pip freeze".  It will list all of the modules particular to your installation or [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), along with their version numbers.  Unfortunately, it does not display the current version number of any module, nor does it wash your dishes or shine your shoes.

Comment: There is also `pip list --local` for distinguishing between `virtualenv` and global site packages, [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24661035/1959808).

Comment: By far the best. It also retrieves the versions.

Comment: `pip list` is the simplest and the best. [Here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_list/) are the options and details.

Comment: `pip list` returns **distributions**, not modules. Distributions and modules have the same name enough to make it seem like this returns modules. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958089/3936044)

Answer (score 95):

- In [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) you can type "`import`<kbd>Tab</kbd>".
- In the standard Python interpreter, you can type "`help('modules')`".
- At the command-line, you can use [`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) `modules`.
- In a script, call [`pkgutil.iter_modules()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules).

Comment: `pkgutil.iter_modules()` works, the pip solution above doesn't list all packages, just the ones installed via pip.

Comment: Awesome! I think they have improved documentation, since the question was asked. **pydoc modules spam** searches spam in docs of modules. The last point seems to give you the sufficient information to use the module. @metaperture Can you, please, give an example how you list all local modules installed (not the massive list of stlib by help('modules')) by **pkgutil.iter_modules()**.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Try this snippet: `python -c 'import pkgutil;print [x[1] for x in list(pkgutil.iter_modules())]'`. It should dump all the module names as one really big Python list.

The `x[1]` bit is used to pluck the module name out of the tuples generated by `pkgutil.iter_modules()`.

Answer (score 94):

I just use this to see currently used modules:

```
import sys as s
s.modules.keys()
```

which shows all modules running on your python.

For all built-in modules use:

```
s.modules
```

Which is a dict containing all modules and import objects.

Comment: # After you import sys "import sys as s" you can print with:                  print sys.modules.keys()

Comment: Not sure why my post was edited, but thank you for using the info I posted to correct the mistakes in prior posts. You will return errors if you use help() vs help(''). This goes for dir('') & sys('') etc. as well. Hope this helps & is not removed.

Comment: Ignore my last post, this post was not edited. I was thinking of a similar post found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module/11173131#11173131 Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Upvoted, because this is the only method that seems to work on constrained systems which have neither `pydoc` nor `pip` installed (a NAS in my case).

Comment: Agreed with Thomas. I'm using repl.it , for example, which is also a constrained type of environment. `help('modules')` just hangs without response for me. But this approach with `sys` works perfectly

Comment: This works in Python 2.6, too, without having to start the Python shell with root privileges ("sudo python") on Linux, as does "help('modules')".  Output is on one long, messy line, but can easily be cleaned up for viewing by copying it into a text editor and replacing all commas with a newline.

Answer (score 67):

In a normal shell, just use

```
pydoc modules
```

Comment: It appears that the above works only on 'nix platforms. In any case, I found and ran the script, adapting the command as follows: c:\bin\pythos_2.7\lib\pydoc.py modules - that list took forever to build, the format sucks, and it omits the installed version number. I'll pass.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray Just tried this on a Windows machine with Python 3, and it does in fact work. Using the python windows launcher you can do `py -m pydoc modules` in cmd or Powershell.

Comment: `pydoc modules` didn't work for me in Windows 10 with Python 3.6, but @VKK modification: `py -m pydoc modules` does work in cmd/Powershell.

Comment: What is *"a normal shell"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *Last seen more than 2 years ago*

Answer (score 63):

As of pip 10, the accepted answer will no longer work.  The development team has removed access to the `get_installed_distributions` routine.  There is an alternate function in the `setuptools` for doing the same thing.  Here is an alternate version that works with pip 10:

```
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

Please let me know if it will or won't work in previous versions of pip, too.

Comment: I have been searching for this solution and wracking my brain trying to figure out pkg_resources.  If I could upvote this more than once I would.  Thank you, @Big_Al_Tx !

Update: Except.... when I do a 'pip freeze' in my virtual environment and compare it to the output of this, there are packages that are missing.  Any thoughts on why that could/would happen?

Comment: @numberwhun - I'm glad this worked for you.  I'm sorry, but I don't have an answer for the discrepancy with `pip freeze`; the depth of my knowledge on this topic is rather limited. I sort-of fumbled my way to the solution when the accepted answer didn't work for me and I tried combining it with an answer related to `setuptools` and got it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243 -  The talk of development team about removed access to the `get_installed_distributions routine`.

Comment: @bl79 - I think that's the exact place where I got the reference for `setuptools`.

Comment: @Big_Al_Tx: Well, I sort of worked around the setuptools option (which was waaaay to obfuscated for my needs) and I went with this:

  installed_pkgs = subprocess.check_output(['pip', 'freeze']) 
It does exactly what I needed it to do.... Yay!!

Comment: @numberwhun - Thanks for the follow-up.  I'll have to check that out myself!

Comment: This works for me.  It returns all installed packages in a Python list format.        
HOW CAN THIS BE MOVED UP TO THE TOP OF THIS POST AND BECOME THE ACCEPTED ANSWER FOR PYTHON 3.7.1 AND PIP > v10+

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD -- It only moves up higher in the list of responses as it gets more user "up" votes.  The original poster accepted the answer above when they got that answer back in 2014, and I don't think it can be changed now.  But I'm glad it worked for you and thanks for the support!

Comment: this should be the answer here.

Comment: `working_set` returns **distributions**, not modules. Distributions and modules have the same name enough to make it seem like this returns modules. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958089/3936044)

Comment: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-list-installed-python-packages/

Comment: This is now deprecated: `DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html`. The documentation suggests to look at `importlib`, though I couldn't find a way to list distributions.

Comment: After some more searching, it seems that a good replacement would be `importlib.metadata.distributions()`.

Comment: @GiovanniMascellani - Thanks for the update. I'm about to migrate to a new computer, so this will be useful to me very soon!

Answer (score 42):

### Works Regardless of Pip Version

Run the following in your python editor or IPython:

```
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = {d.project_name: d.version for d in pkg_resources.working_set}
print(installed_packages)
```

Read other answers and pulled together this combo, which is quickest and easiest *inside Python*.

#### Find the specific Packages

Conveniently you can then get items from your dict easily, i.e.

`installed_packages['pandas']` >> '1.16.4'

#### Using Pip List Well

`!pip list` will run inside your jupyter notebook if working there, simplifying the 'quick check'
Combine with other utilities like grep(if you have installed)
`pip list | grep pandas`  will get you your current pandas version for example

Comment: `pkg_resources` is part of _setuptools_. It has not much to do with _pip_.

Comment: Yep @sinoroc, but the accepted answer doesn't work beyond pip 10 which was the intent of the title

Comment: Then I don't understand the logic of your title, since your solution is not limited to recent versions of pip. It should work for any version of _pip_ since it doesn't use _pip_ at all. Also you might want to look at `importlib.metadata` from Python's standard library since 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html

Comment: `working_set` returns **distributions**, not modules. Distributions and modules have the same name enough to make it seem like this returns modules. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958089/3936044)

Answer (score 39):

If we need to list the installed packages in the Python shell, we can use the `help` command as follows

```
>>> help('modules package')
```

Comment: Only returns modules which has the word `package` in it's name or in it's docstring, which a lot of modules does not have.

Answer (score 26):

I normally use `pip list` to get a list of packages (with version).

This works in a virtual environment too, of course. To show what's installed in only the virtual environment (not global packages), use `pip list --local`.

[Here's documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/) showing all the available `pip list` options, with several good examples.

Answer (score 23):

`$ pip freeze` -- Output installed packages in requirements format
`$ pip list`   -- List installed packages.

Answer (score 19):

#### This will help

In a terminal or [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), type:

```
help('modules')
```

then

```
In [1]: import                      #import press-TAB
Display all 631 possibilities? (y or n)
ANSI                   audiodev               markupbase
AptUrl                 audioop                markupsafe
ArgImagePlugin         avahi                  marshal
BaseHTTPServer         axi                    math
Bastion                base64                 md5
BdfFontFile            bdb                    mhlib
BmpImagePlugin         binascii               mimetools
BufrStubImagePlugin    binhex                 mimetypes
CDDB                   bisect                 mimify
CDROM                  bonobo                 mmap
CGIHTTPServer          brlapi                 mmkeys
Canvas                 bsddb                  modulefinder
CommandNotFound        butterfly              multifile
ConfigParser           bz2                    multiprocessing
ContainerIO            cPickle                musicbrainz2
Cookie                 cProfile               mutagen
Crypto                 cStringIO              mutex
CurImagePlugin         cairo                  mx
DLFCN                  calendar               netrc
DcxImagePlugin         cdrom                  new
Dialog                 cgi                    nis
DiscID                 cgitb                  nntplib
DistUpgrade            checkbox               ntpath
```

Answer (score 13):

Very simple searching using [pkgutil.iter_modules](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules)

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules
a=iter_modules()
while True:
    try: x=a.next()
    except: break
    if 'searchstr' in x[1]: print x[1]
```

Comment: is there any reason to use while instead of a for loop? I wrote using `for m in iter_modules()` and it did work as well.

Comment: [m.name for m in iter_modules() if '_' not in m.name and not any([ex in m.name for ex in ['easy_install', 'pip', 'wheel', 'setuptool', 'pkg_resources'] ])]
First it removes the underscore named modules, then it removes items in the exception list.
:D

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, enter this in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
cd C:\python\libs
python -m pip freeze
```

Comment: This worked for me using:  python3 -m pip freeze  - for python 3.5.3.

Comment: This works well and you do not need to be in the libs directory as well if your variables are defined

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a custom installed python 2.7 on OS X. It required X11 to list modules installed (both using help and pydoc).

To be able to list all modules without installing X11 I ran pydoc as http-server, i.e.:

```
pydoc -p 12345
```

Then it's possible to direct Safari to `http://localhost:12345/` to see all modules.

Answer (score 12):

This solution is primary based on modules `importlib` and `pkgutil` and work with CPython 3.4 and CPython 3.5, but has no support for the CPython 2.

---

**Explanation**

1. `sys.builtin_module_names` - names all built-in modules (look my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673644/6003870))
2. `pkgutil.iter_modules()` - returns an information about all available modules
3. `importlib.util.find_spec()` - returns an information about importing module, if exists
4. `BuiltinImporter` - an importer for built-in modules ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter))
5. `SourceFileLoader` - an importer for a standard Python module (by default has extension *.py) ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader))
6. `ExtensionFileLoader` - an importer for modules as [shared library](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) (written on the C or C++)

---

**Full code**

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
import pkgutil
import importlib
import collections

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    raise NotImplementedError('CPython 2 is not supported yet')


def main():

    # Name this file (module)
    this_module_name = os.path.basename(__file__).rsplit('.')[0]

    # Dict for loaders with their modules
    loaders = collections.OrderedDict()

    # Names's of build-in modules
    for module_name in sys.builtin_module_names:

        # Find an information about a module by name
        module = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)

        # Add a key about a loader in the dict, if not exists yet
        if module.loader not in loaders:
            loaders[module.loader] = []

        # Add a name and a location about imported module in the dict
        loaders[module.loader].append((module.name, module.origin))

    # All available non-build-in modules
    for module_name in pkgutil.iter_modules():

        # Ignore this module
        if this_module_name == module_name[1]:
            continue

        # Find an information about a module by name
        module = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name[1])

        # Add a key about a loader in the dict, if not exists yet
        loader = type(module.loader)
        if loader not in loaders:
            loaders[loader] = []

        # Add a name and a location about imported module in the dict
        loaders[loader].append((module.name, module.origin))

    # Pretty print
    line = '-' * shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
    for loader, modules in loaders.items():
        print('{0}\n{1}: {2}\n{0}'.format(line, len(modules), loader))
        for module in modules:
            print('{0:30} | {1}'.format(module[0], module[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Usage**

For the CPython 3.5 (truncated)

```
python3.5 python_modules_info.py
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30: <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_ast                           | built-in
_codecs                        | built-in
_collections                   | built-in
_functools                     | built-in
_imp                           | None
_io                            | built-in
_locale                        | built-in
_operator                      | built-in
_signal                        | built-in
_sre                           | built-in
_stat                          | built-in
_string                        | built-in
_symtable                      | built-in
_thread                        | built-in
(****************************truncated*******************************)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
227: <class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__future__                     | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/__future__.py
_bootlocale                    | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_bootlocale.py
_collections_abc               | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py
_compat_pickle                 | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_compat_pickle.py
_compression                   | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_compression.py
_dummy_thread                  | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_dummy_thread.py
_markupbase                    | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_markupbase.py
_osx_support                   | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_osx_support.py
_pydecimal                     | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_pydecimal.py
_pyio                          | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_pyio.py
_sitebuiltins                  | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/_sitebuiltins.py
(****************************truncated*******************************)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64: <class '_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_bisect                        | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_bz2                           | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_cn                     | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_hk                     | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_iso2022                | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
(****************************truncated*******************************)
```

For the CPython 3.4 (truncated)

```
python3.4 python_modules_info.py
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54: <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_ast                           | built-in
_bisect                        | built-in
_codecs                        | built-in
_collections                   | built-in
_datetime                      | built-in
_elementtree                   | built-in
_functools                     | built-in
_heapq                         | built-in
_imp                           | None
_io                            | built-in
_locale                        | built-in
_md5                           | built-in
_operator                      | built-in
_pickle                        | built-in
_posixsubprocess               | built-in
_random                        | built-in
(****************************truncated*******************************)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
246: <class '_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__future__                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/__future__.py
_bootlocale                    | /usr/lib/python3.4/_bootlocale.py
_collections_abc               | /usr/lib/python3.4/_collections_abc.py
_compat_pickle                 | /usr/lib/python3.4/_compat_pickle.py
_dummy_thread                  | /usr/lib/python3.4/_dummy_thread.py
_markupbase                    | /usr/lib/python3.4/_markupbase.py
_osx_support                   | /usr/lib/python3.4/_osx_support.py
_pyio                          | /usr/lib/python3.4/_pyio.py
(****************************truncated*******************************)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44: <class '_frozen_importlib.ExtensionFileLoader'>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_bz2                           | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_cn                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_hk                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_iso2022                | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_jp                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_kr                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_tw                     | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_crypt                         | /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_crypt.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
(****************************truncated*******************************)
```

Comment: Can you please compare your approach to Adam's approach here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/54964

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz, why are you need it?

Comment: To understand how your approach is better/worser than Adam's approach.

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz. A short answer: try it yourself in a production and draw conclusions yourself. Long answer: the Adam's approach is based on the `pip` - package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python and a result `pip.get_installed_distributions()` returns modules installed with the pip. My answer entirely based on the Python`s standard library and cover all modules available for import. A biggest drawback my answer - no a support for the the CPython 2.

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz you are mistaken, it does it. I tested it on my computer. My answer contains special meaning `**truncated**`, where a output is truncated. Maybe you not careful, but if it does not it, so to send me an information about your system and the Python implementation, I will make addition research for fix it.

Comment: Excellent, this should be in PyPI!

Answer (score 12):

I'm comparing **five** methods to retrieve installed "modules", all of which I've seen in this thread

|  | iter_modules | help("modules") | builtin_module_names | pip list | working_set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Includes distributions | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Includes modules (No built-in) | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ |
| Includes built-in modules | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ❌ |
| Includes frozen | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ |
| Includes venv | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Includes global | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Includes editable installs | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Includes PyCharm helpers | ✔️ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ |
| Lowers capital letters | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| Time taken (665 modules total) | 53.7 msec | 1.03 sec | 577 nsec | 284 msec | 36.2 usec |

### Summary

- `pip list` and `working_set` are for **distributions**, not modules.
- `iter_modules` and `help("modules")` are very similar, the biggest difference is that `iter_modules` doesn't include built-in.
- `pip list` and `working_set` are very similar, only difference is that `working_set` lowers all capital letters.
- Built-in modules are only included by `help("modules")` and `builtin_module_names`.

#### Related caveats

- Distributions, packages, and modules often have identical names making it easy to mistake one for the other.
- `importlib.util.find_spec` is for modules and is case-sensitive.
- `sys.modules` only lists imported modules.

#### Distributions

I'm saying distribution instead of package because I think it will reduce misunderstandings. A distribution/package can have multiple packages/modules inside it.

An installed distribution is not always importable by the same name. For example `pip install Pillow` is imported with `import PIL`. Sometimes a distribution even makes multiple modules importable.

### Methods *(Each column in order)*

##### iter_modules

```py
import pkgutil
{module.name for module in pkgutil.iter_modules()}
```

##### help("modules") *(Only prints in terminal)*

```py
help("modules")
```

##### builtin_module_names

```py
import sys
set(sys.builtin_module_names)
```

##### pip list *(Only prints in terminal)*

`pip list` in terminal

##### working_set

```py
import pkg_resources
{pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
```

#### Conclusion

- For terminal I recommend `help("modules")` or `python -c "help('modules')"`.

  - [Top voted answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740018/3936044)
- For programmatically I recommend `iter_modules` + `builtin_module_names`.

  - [This answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673938/3936044)

    - It is however very convoluted with information, see my minimal example below.

```py
import sys
import pkgutil

def get_installed_modules_names():
    iter_modules = {module.name for module in pkgutil.iter_modules()}
    builtin = sys.builtin_module_names
    return set.union(iter_modules, builtin)
```

Comment: That is a VERY good complement to the answer just above yours : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673938/1841533 (and both of your answers seem far better than most of the top ones)

Answer (score 10):

**Warning: Adam Matan discourages this use in pip > 10.0. Also, read @sinoroc's comment below**

This was inspired by Adam Matan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/277267) (the accepted one):

```
import tabulate
try:
  from pip import get_installed_distributions
except:
  from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions

tabpackages = []
for _, package in sorted([('%s %s' % (i.location, i.key), i) for i in get_installed_distributions()]):
  tabpackages.append([package.location, package.key, package.version])

print(tabulate.tabulate(tabpackages))
```

which then prints out a table in the form of

```
cd ~/python
python installed_packages.py
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------  --------------  ------
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  enum-compat     0.0.2
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  enum34          1.1.6
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  pexpect         4.2.1
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  ptyprocess      0.5.2
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  pygatt          3.2.0
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  pyserial        3.4
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       bluepy          1.1.1
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       click           6.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       click-datetime  0.2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       construct       2.8.21
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       pyaudio         0.2.11
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages       tabulate        0.8.2
-------------------------------------------  --------------  ------
```

which lets you then easily discern which packages you installed with and without `sudo`.

---

A note aside: I've noticed that when I install a packet once via `sudo` and once without, one takes precedence so that the other one isn't being listed (only one location is shown). I believe that only the one in the local directory is then listed. This could be improved.

Comment: No. This is not recommended, see here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you for pointing this out. Points 1 to 3 don't seem to be applicable to this solution, as this script has the sole purpose of using `pip` once and then exiting. It appears to be more of a problem that the behavior could change.

Comment: Agreed, the reasons why there is no public API do not apply to this particular piece of code. But since pip is not bound to guarantee a public API it is free to change its internal APIs, code structure, etc. in a later release, like it already did before. This is why this code has a try/except, to catch the previous internal code reorganization that was meant to clarify that internal APIs are internal APIs not public ones (`_internal`). All in all, it obviously works but is bad practice. There are better alternatives, some are in the other answers to this question.

Comment: this script wont work if the "pip" module is not there.

Answer (score 9):

In case you have an [Anaconda Python distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) installed, you could also use

```
conda list
```

in addition to the solutions described in previous answers.

Comment: Where/how do you run this line?

Comment: If you are on your UNIX/Mac OS X machine, open up your terminal and just type `conda install`, it should work :)

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 machine.  I found it in my path actually, but conda.exe is in AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from using `pip freeze` I have been installing [yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk) in my virtual environments.

Answer (score 6):

1. to get all available modules, run `sys.modules`
2. to get all *installed* modules (read: installed by `pip`), you may look at `pip.get_installed_distributions()`

For the second purpose, example code:

```
import pip
for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    name = package.project_name # SQLAlchemy, Django, Flask-OAuthlib
    key = package.key # sqlalchemy, django, flask-oauthlib
    module_name = package._get_metadata("top_level.txt") # sqlalchemy, django, flask_oauthlib
    location = package.location # virtualenv lib directory etc.
    version = package.version # version number
```

Comment: The command **sys.modules** does not work in the newest OSX's Python. **NameError: name 'system' is not defined**.

Comment: @Masi Did you mean `/usr/bin/python` or the one come from http://python.org ? For the former one, I can use `sys.modules` without a problem.

Comment: I mean **/usr/bin/python**.

Comment: @Masi Not sure if you are still interested in this problem. Apparently you are using `system.modules` instead of `sys.modules`.

Comment: Lol. My mistake was that I did not originally import sys -package. So running instead **import sys; sys.modules** work as expected.

Comment: No. This is not recommended, see here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Comment: Note the answer was from 2014 and thus is outdated. @sinoroc could you add an answer with your comment? I will upvote yours instead. Not sure how I should deal with the existing answer...

Comment: @yegle Thanks for coming back on this. I am wondering how to deal with outdated answers as well. In many cases voting them down is far from enough, they still either have too many votes or are the accepted one. Maybe add a prominent "**OUTDATED**" note right at the beginning (better than deleting, since maybe the user would lose their points, and since it might still have some "_historical_" value). I wouldn't add another answer of mine since there are too many high-voted answers already, but I would maybe recommend this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50013400/11138259

Answer (score 5):

**pip freeze** does it all, finding packages. However, one can simply write the following command to list all paths where Python packages are.

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 4):

*There are many way to skin a cat.*

- The most simple way is to use the `pydoc` function directly from the shell with:
  `pydoc modules`
- But for more information use the tool called [pip-date](https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date) that also tell you the installation dates.
  `pip install pip-date`

---

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54396916/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to find the specific version of packages available by default in AWS Lambda. I did so with a mashup of ideas from this page. I'm sharing it for posterity.

```
import pkgutil

__version__ = '0.1.1'

def get_ver(name):
    try:
        return str(__import__(name).__version__)
    except:
        return None

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': [{
                   'path': m.module_finder.path,
                   'name': m.name,
                   'version': get_ver(m.name),
                 } for m in list(pkgutil.iter_modules())
                 #if m.module_finder.path == "/var/runtime" # Uncomment this if you only care about a certain path
                ],
    }
```

What I discovered is that the provided boto3 library was way out of date and it wasn't my fault that my code was failing. I just needed to add boto3 and botocore to my project. But without this I would have been banging my head thinking my code was bad.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": [
    {
      "path": "/var/task",
      "name": "lambda_function",
      "version": "0.1.1"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "bootstrap",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "boto3",
      "version": "1.9.42"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "botocore",
      "version": "1.12.42"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "dateutil",
      "version": "2.7.5"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "docutils",
      "version": "0.14"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "jmespath",
      "version": "0.9.3"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "lambda_runtime_client",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "lambda_runtime_exception",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "lambda_runtime_marshaller",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "s3transfer",
      "version": "0.1.13"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "six",
      "version": "1.11.0"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "test_bootstrap",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "test_lambda_runtime_client",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "test_lambda_runtime_marshaller",
      "version": null
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/runtime",
      "name": "urllib3",
      "version": "1.24.1"
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/lang/lib/python3.7",
      "name": "__future__",
      "version": null
    },
...
```

What I discovered was also different from [what they officially publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). At the time of writing this:

> - Operating system – Amazon Linux
> - AMI – amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2
> - Linux kernel – 4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64
> - AWS SDK for JavaScript – 2.290.0\
> - SDK for Python (Boto 3) – 3-1.7.74 botocore-1.10.74

Answer (score 3):

There are many ideas, initially I am pondering on these two:

**pip**

> cons: not always installed

**help('modules')**

> cons: output to console; with broken modules (see ubuntu...) can segfault

I need an easy approach, using basic libraries and compatible with old python 2.x

And I see the light: [listmodules.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r256/Doc/tools/listmodules.py)

Hidden in the documentation source directory in 2.5 is a small script that lists all available modules for a Python installation.

Pros:

> uses only *imp, sys, os, re, time*
>
> designed to run on Python 1.5.2 and newer
>
> the source code is really compact, so you can easy tinkering with it, for example to pass an exception list of buggy modules (don't try to import them)

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install pip-chill 
pip-chill
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python code solution that will return a list of modules installed. One can easily modify the code to include version numbers.

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from pprint import pprint

installed_packages = reqs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze']).decode('utf-8')
installed_packages = installed_packages.split('\r\n')
installed_packages = [pkg.split('==')[0] for pkg in installed_packages if pkg != '']
pprint(installed_packages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation

```
pip install pkgutil
```

Code

```
import pkgutil

for i in pkgutil.iter_modules(None): # returns a tuple (path, package_name, ispkg_flag)
    print(i[1]) #or you can append it to a list
```

Sample Output:

```
multiprocessing
netrc
nntplib
ntpath
nturl2path
numbers
opcode
pickle
pickletools
pipes
pkgutil
```

Answer (score 1):

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

> Attention
>
> Use of pkg_resources is deprecated in favor of importlib.resources, importlib.metadata and their backports (importlib_resources, importlib_metadata). Some useful APIs are also provided by packaging (e.g. requirements and version parsing). Users should refrain from new usage of pkg_resources and should work to port to importlib-based solutions.

## using python 3.12+ importlib

```
import importlib.metadata

def list_installed_packages():
    distributions = importlib.metadata.distributions()
    installed_packages = []
    for dist in distributions:
        args = (dist.metadata['Name'], dist.version)
        installed_packages.append(args)
    installed_packages.sort()  # Sort the packages by name
    for package_name, version in installed_packages:
        print(f"{package_name}=={version}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_installed_packages()
```

- https://gist.github.com/allen-munsch/c785489dd57ebf9e4f6af45095ac8daa
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#overview
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions

Comment: Thanks for this answer, a couple of changes and it now replaces `pkg_resources.working_set` for my auto module installer. Handy as Python 3.12+ is killing that off.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the previous answers seem to help: In my environment, it was broken from a system upgrade and I could not upgrade *pip*.

While it won't give you an accurate list, you can get an idea of which libraries were installed simply by looking inside your *env* → *lib* → *python(version here)* → *site-packages* →. Here you will get a good indication of modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pip3 freeze
```

Run this command globally. It will show you all the global installations.
Run this command on the virtual environment. It will show you all the local installations.

Answer (score -3):

For anyone wondering how to call `pip list` from a Python program you can use the following:

```
import pip
pip.main(['list])  # this will print all the packages
```

Comment: No. This is not recommended, see here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Answer (score -11):

From the shell

```
ls site-packages
```

If that's not helpful, you can do this.

```
import sys
import os
for p in sys.path:
    print os.listdir( p )
```

And see what that produces.

Comment: which site-packages directory? This might do better:

    ls /usr/{local/,}lib/python$(python -V 2>&1|cut -d" " -f2 |cut -d. -f1-2)/site-packages

Comment: Also this will not show built-in modules, or modules in a custom PYTHONPATH, or ones installed in setuptools "development mode" etc.

Comment: My /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages is empty, although I have installed modules.

Comment: @dF: While true, I don't see how any of those alternatives are relevant to the question.

Comment: @Masi: Interesting.  You'll have to look at sys.path to see all the places they might have been put.

Comment: Kudos for not deleting this downvoted answer.  It's helpful to the community to be able to see why a common answer is considered wrong.

Comment: @JeremyStein A better strategy (more helpful and probably less rep-damaging) would probably be to edit the question to explain why it's wrong, once this has been explained in the comments...

Comment: `ls site-packages`:  `ls: cannot access 'site-packages': No such file or directory` ([Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), from "the" home directory)

Comment: What shell? In what context? What version(s)? In what configuration?

Comment: Perhaps it is time for an update? But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar—the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: Sample location: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`

Comment: [Finding it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory/31384782#31384782).