# Where are the python modules stored?

Tags: python, directory, module

I have recently started learning Python and I have 2 questions relating to modules.

1. Is there a way to obtain a list of Python modules available (i.e. installed) on a machine?
2. I am using Ubuntu Karmic and Synaptic for package management. I have just installed a python module.Where is the module code actually stored on my machine? (is there a default [recommended] location that modules are stored)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/unable-to-get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules

Comment: If you import `sys` then run `sys.path()`, it shows all the paths for python. `/usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages` worked for me.

Comment: In python 3.9, `path` is not a function, it's `A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to obtain a list of
>    Python modules available (i.e.
>    installed) on a machine?

This works for me:

```
help('modules')
```

> 2. Where is the module code actually
>    stored on my machine?

Usually in `/lib/site-packages` in your Python folder. (At least, on Windows.)

You can use [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) to find out what directories are searched for modules.

Comment: If you want the location of a specific module, `import` it and look at it's `__file__` attribute. Works for most of them.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim your answer is worth like the answer itself. TY. you can append it to make it bold for users.

Answer (score 140):

On python command line, first import that module for which you need location.

```
import module_name
```

Then type:

```
print(module_name.__file__)
```

For example to find out "pygal" location:

```
import pygal
print(pygal.__file__)
```

Output:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygal/__init__.py
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got this error: `Unable to initialize device PRN`, any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 37):

If you are using `pip`:

```
pip show <package name>
```

Sample output of `pip show tensorflow`:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.1.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: termcolor, six, astor, numpy, grpcio, absl-py, protobuf, tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard, gast, keras-applications, opt-einsum, wheel, keras-preprocessing, google-pasta, scipy, wrapt
Required-by: tf-models-official
```

The installed location is shown at `Location:/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Answer (score 20):

On Windows machine python modules are located at (system drive and python version may vary):

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib
```

Comment: I guess it is best practice to use `%appdata%` in the address window of the Explorer to get quickly to the `Roaming` folder and jump back and forth to the `Local` folder then.

Comment: Where are python modules stored on Linux?

Comment: Note: I found mine in **C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages**, probably because I installed python differently...

Comment: @AndyS You probably are using python 3.9

Answer (score 12):

You can find module code by first listing the modules:

```
help("modules")
```

This spits out a list of modules Python can import. At the bottom of this list is a phrase:

> Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to
>   search for modules whose name or summary contain the string "spam".

To find module location:

```
help("module_Name")
```

for example:

```
help("signal")
```

A lot of information here. Scroll to the bottom to find its location

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py
```

Copy link. To see code, after exiting Python REPL:

```
nano /usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You can iterate through directories listed in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) to find all modules (except builtin ones).
2. It'll probably be somewhere around `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` (again, see `sys.path`). And consider using native Python package management (via [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/0.7.2) or [`easy_install`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall), plus [`yolk`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.1)) instead, packages in Linux distros-maintained repositories tend to be outdated.

Answer (score 5):

Run python CLI for info

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Using the help function**

Get into the python prompt and type the following command:

```
>>>help("modules")
```

This will list all the modules installed in the system. You don't need to install any additional packages to list them, but you need to manually search or filter the required module from the list.

**2) Using pip freeze**

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip freeze
```

Even though you need to install additional packages to use this, this method allows you to easily search or filter the result with `grep` command. e.g. `pip freeze | grep feed`.

You can use whichever method is convenient for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `conda` or `pip` to install modules you can use

```
pip list
```

or

```
conda list
```

to display all the modules. This will display all the modules in the terminal itself and is much faster than

```py
>>> help('modules')
```

Comment: Yes, `pip list | grep module_name_or_part_of_name` to check for a particular module.

Comment: This shows you modules but doesn't tell you where the modules are stored

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, use grep to find a chosen module, no extra installation needed for that, quickly done.

The `-r` stands for recursive search in the sub-directories and the l to show only the files, not the directories. Usually you can see the locations from the upcoming list, and you can stop the output with Ctrl-C.

```
grep -rl module_name_or_part_of_name /
```

or, borrowed from the value comment here from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3260548/oak-3260548):

```
pip list | grep module_name_or_part_of_name
```

Answer (score 0):

On my local machine (Win 10), it has the following path:

```
c:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.meta_path` is another source of modules, in addition to `sys.path`. It contains info that `help('module')` doesn't.

`meta_path` can explain unexpected import behaviors - if a module isn't on `sys.path`, it doesn't guarantee it won't be imported. Moreover, if a package *is* on `sys.path`, but a package with same name but different directory is in `sys.meta_path`, Python will import from both, prioritizing `sys.path`. This can be troublesome if you've intentionally removed something from the package in `sys.path` - Python will keep importing it from `sys.meta_path`. This includes certain non-Python files, like Cython's `.pyx` builds.

Answer (score 0):

On a 2023 Windows machine with Python 3.8 or later installed with defaults:

Press the Windows key, paste or type the following and press enter

```
explorer %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python
```

This opens `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python` which contains directories named per the various versions of Python installed (perhaps, in the past), and their respective installed packages.