# No module named sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to install sklearn module through `pip`, but below is the error i am encountered.

[image]

Comment: in windows if u want to install python packages you should mention python site packages directory. In ubuntu and mac os u need not mention path of that directory.Let's mention the python directory. Hope this link will useful for u [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927993/where-are-the-python-modules-stored]

Answer (score 1):

I think error code 1 actually refers to missing Lapack/Blast dependencies on your windows installation. Lapack/BLAST are requirements for most scientific Python packages for example : numpy, scipy, sklearn etc...

You could either build these for source and then pip install sklearn

Instructions for this here > http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html

Or just install anaconda and not have any of these issues. If you want to do advanced data analytics with Python, I would recommend using Anaconda especially in windows machine where any scipy package installation will be like fighting with windmills

Instructions how to get Anaconda here > https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows

Further tip. I would go with Anaconda full 3.6 for your dev machine so you have all that you might need out of the box. This includes popular science, data manipulation and math packages + Jupyper (iPython) notebooks and Spider IDE for development. 
For server you only want required packages so use miniconda there.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Anaconda and there type in `conda install scikit-learn` in the console.