# How do I list the libraries that exist in python?

Tags: python

For example, in rails you can do a 'gem list' and it will show all of the gems that you have installed.

Any clue how I can do this in python?  Also, I am using virtualenv, not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
help('modules')
```

is supposed to do it (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/unable-to-get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules)).

Note: When I did it, I got a segmentation fault due to one of the libraries (I'm on Ubuntu).

Comment: As of July 2012, this gives me a seg fault as well. Using yolk as answered by pyfunc works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/unable-to-get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules):

`help('modules')` in a Python prompt, or `pydoc modules` in a regular shell.

Answer (score 4):

**Since there are many ways.**

You can try module **[yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk)**

> easy_install yolk or pip install yolk

and list installed modules using

> yolk -l

It's far more powerful. It can also allow you too check for updates. See the documentation for details. I have been using this package a lot.

> yolk -U

Comment: +1 Looks like a really useful tool!

Answer (score 3):

Install `pip` and do `pip freeze`.

If you are using virtualenv, it is already installed in it.

Comment: Another solution that works. It should be noted though that this also catches all globally installed modules as well. Depending on what the author wants, this could be bad/good (he may only want to list virtualenv installed modules, although that's as easy as going into the virtualenv site-packages folder).

Comment: Actualy you should read about `pip` http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html if you are going to get benefits of using virtualenv.

Comment: @JohnDoe under virtualenv configured with --no-site-packages it will show only packages installed in this virtualenv.

Comment: True. It all depends on the virtualenv configuration in such a case. :)

Comment: Starting from pip 1.3 there's a [list](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-list) command.