# Print everything that can be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to get a list of installed Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/unable-to-get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules)

How do I print a list of all the modules that are available for import from within my script in Python3?

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) you can type "`import`<kbd>Tab</kbd>".

In the standard Python interpreter, you can type "`help('modules')`".

At the command-line, you can use [`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) `modules`.

Answer (score 6):

To access the list of all installed modules accessible via `sys.path` *programmatically* rather than inside an interactive session, you can use [`pkgutil.iter_modules()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules).