# pip installs package twice

Tags: python, package, pip, virtualenv

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it, but we have seen it several times:

> pip installs one packages twice.

If you uninstall the first, the second gets visible and can get uninstalled, too.

My question: How can I check with python if a package is installed twice?

Background: I want to write a test which checks this (devOp)

**Update**

- Packages are installed in a virtualenv.
- The two packages have different versions.
- This is not a duplicate of solutions which solve this by hand. I search a solution to detect this with python code. How to resolve this is not part if my question.

**Update 2**

The command `pip freeze` outputs the package only once:

```
pip freeze | grep -i south
South==0.8.1
```

But in the virtual-env it exists twice:

```
find lib -name top_level.txt |xargs cat | grep -i south
south
south

ls lib/python2.7/site-packages/| grep -i south
south
South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg
South-0.8.4-py2.7.egg-info
```

Comment: This question might help you with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166014/how-to-tell-if-you-have-multiple-djangos-installed

Comment: are they different versions? is one installed globablly and one installed in your virtualenv?

Comment: @guettli It is really pity, you cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method to check if a package is installed twice:

```
def test_pip_python_packages_installed_twice(self):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941861/633961
    pkg_name_to_locations=defaultdict(set)
    for dist in pkg_resources.working_set:
        for pkg_name in dist._get_metadata('top_level.txt'):
            for location in sys.path:
                try:
                    importutils.does_module_exist_at_given_path(pkg_name, [location])
                except ImportError:
                    continue
                if location.startswith('/usr'):
                    # ignore packages from "root" level.
                    continue
                pkg_name_to_locations[pkg_name].add(location)

    errors=dict()
    for pkg_name, locations in sorted(pkg_name_to_locations.items()):
        if pkg_name in ['_markerlib', 'pkg_resources', 'site', 'easy_install', 'setuptools', 'pip']:
            continue
        if len(locations)==1:
            continue
        errors[pkg_name]=locations
    self.assertFalse(errors, 
                     'Some modules are installed twice:\n%s' % '\n'.join(['%s: %s' % (key, value) for key, value in sorted(errors.items())]))
```

importutils

```
def does_module_exist_at_given_path(module_name, path):
    '''
    imp.find_module() does not find zipped eggs.
    Needed for check: check if a package is installed twice.
    '''
    for path_item in path:
        result=None
        try:
            result=imp.find_module(module_name, [path_item])
        except ImportError:
            pass

        if result:
            return bool(result)
        if not os.path.isfile(path_item):
            continue
        # could be a zipped egg
        module=zipimport.zipimporter(path_item).find_module(module_name)
        if module:
            return bool(module)
    raise ImportError(module_name)
```

Related: [imp.find_module() which supports zipped eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962344/imp-find-module-which-supports-zipped-eggs)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def count_installs(pkg_name):
    import imp, sys
    n = 0
    for location in sys.path:
        try:
            imp.find_module(pkg_name, [location])
        except ImportError: pass
        else: n += 1
    return n
```

e.g.

```
>>> count_installs("numpy")
2
>>> count_installs("numpyd")
0
>>> count_installs("sympy")
1
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. A wrote a unittest which loops over all packages in the working set. See below.

Answer (score 0):

`South-0.8.1-py2.7.egg` is a zip archive with *South* source code, `South-0.8.4-py2.7.egg-info` is a directory with metadata files for *South* library.

`.egg-info` (for libraries built from `.tar.gz`) or `.dist-info` (for libs installed from wheels `.whl`) are present for every library installed by `pip`.

`.egg` archive is created if the library marked as `zip_safe` in metadata (`setup(zip_safe=True)` in `setup.py`).
Otherwise *pip* makes a directory with extracted python source files.

Very old versions of *setuptools* was able to install several versions of the same library and mark one of them as *active*, but mentioned functionality was dropped for years ago if I recall correctly.