# Using help and pydoc to list python modules not working

Tags: python, python-module, pydoc

I'm trying to find out what modules I have installed for python

from: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules)

I've tried

```
>>> help('modules')
no Python documentation found for 'modules'

>>> pydoc modules
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pydoc modules
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, this works

```
>>> help('numpy')
```

along with any other module I know I have installed.

This *does* return the modules, but **is there a way to fix my help documentation?**

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules
for a in iter_modules():
    print a
```

**Edit**

I installed the 64 bit python 2.7 through the enthought python distribution on Mac OS mtn lion

running pydoc in shell:

```
$ pydoc modules
no Python documentation found for 'modules'
```

Comment: Using `help('modules')` works fine here, both in cpython and in the ipython front-end. How did you install python?

Comment: @Roland: it also works on Jython, Pypy.

Comment: You should run `pydoc modules` from a system shell such as bash, cmd.exe, not Python shell.

Comment: Side note: `pydoc modules` is a syntax error because you should `import pydoc` and `pydoc.help('modules')`. Though, `help` is a wrapper around `pydoc.help`, so even using pydoc that way shouldn't help, too.

Comment: Btw, for me using help('modules') doesn't work; I get a segmentation fault (ubuntu, python 2.7.3)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian right you are, my bad.

Comment: `pip freeze` is also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

help('modules') is deliberately disabled in newer versions of Enthought's Python because it reliably causes segfaults with a standard set of EPD packages.

One way to list all packages you have installed in EPD is with `enpkg -l`.  Note that this tool only lists packages you have installed with the EPD installer or enpkg itself; it won't know about packages you have installed by hand or, for example, with pip.

More info about the enpkg tool can be found by typing `enpkg --help`, or in this Enthought Knowledge Base Article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-using-enpkg-to-update-epd-packages

Answer (score 0):

You can try,
'>>> help()'
in python. This will take you to help prompt, that will look something like -
help>

Here you can type 'modules' to get list of all modules.