# Detect Python transitive dependency issues at install time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, transitive-dependency

I recently learned that [`pip` does not resolve transitive dependencies](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) in any sane fashion.  This means after installing a package, some of its dependencies' dependencies may not actually be satisfied.

Is there a way to programmatically check that all installed packages' dependencies are actually satisfied after installing?

Specifically, I would like to be able to create a virtualenv, install some packages into it, and then verify that all installed packages actually have the required dependencies.

---

**Edit:** Here is an example to better illustrate the problem.  Suppose package `A` depends on packages `B` and `C`, both of which depend on package `D`, possibly with different version ranges.  When installing `A`, pip will arbitrarily choose one of the specified version ranges for `D` to satisfy.  For example, `B`'s dependency on `D` might be satisfied, but `C`'s required version for `D` may not be satisfied.  I want to detect whether such problems exist.

Comment: Yes, use a requirements file and pin your version numbers.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Please see the above question.  I am asking for a way to "Detect Python transitive dependency issues at install time".  I am not asking for a way to avoid transitive dependency issues, especially not by manually resolving dependencies.

Comment: Newer visitors to this question should consider using poetry  https://python-poetry.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457406) shows how to get all locally installed packages.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16298328) shows a way to verify that a given package is installed, which also recursively checks the package's dependencies.  Combining these:

```
import pip
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.require(str(dep.as_requirement())
                      for dep in pip.get_installed_distributions())
```

This will raise a [`ResolutionError`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#exceptions) if any of the installed packages has an unsatisfied requirement.

---

Aside: This seems to be what the new [`pip check`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3750) command is intended to do, but it doesn't catch some dependency issues that the above script catches, such as [extras-related issues](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4086).

---

**Update:** Recent versions of `pip` do not provide a `get_installed_distributions()` function. Per https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243, `pkg_resources.working_set` can be used to get the dependency list:

```
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.require(str(dep.as_requirement())
                      for dep in pkg_resources.working_set)
```