# keras_hub feature extractor layer problem in pycharm

Tags: keras, pycharm

The below code in PyCharm is about transfer learning to add a feature extractor layer into keras sequential model. :

feature_extract_layer=hub.KerasLayer(model_url,trainable=False,input_shape=(224,224,3),name="feature_extraction")
model=tf.keras.Sequential([
feature_extract_layer,
tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_data.num_classes,activation='softmax',name="outputLayer")

])
is giving the below error:

Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received:

> <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x000001C830B446B0>
> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>) code: import
> tensorflow as tf import tensorflow_hub as hub model_url =
> "https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/mobilenet-v2/frameworks/tensorFlow2/variations/100-224-feature-vector/versions/1?tfhub-redirect=true"

I tried the code in google colab and it worked normal, but I need it in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to make sure that keras is version 2.something :
Since TF2.16 comes with Keras3 the problem arises. As a workaround, we can install tf_keras package and set environment variable TF_USE_LEGACY_KERAS=1 to ensure Keras2 will be used with tf.keras.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your environments are equivalent in Google Collab and in your local PyCharm venv?

Check which versions of the packages you have on Collab and then compare them against your local environment. If there are any differences, remove the incorrectly-versioned packages and re-install them with the correct versions.

Comment: i have the latest version in pycharm, so for sure there is an alternative for this code but i dont know what it is

Comment: I'm not talking about the version of PyCharm. I'm talking about the versions of the Python packages you installed in order to run your script.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939975/how-to-list-all-installed-packages-and-their-versions-in-python

Comment: i told you i have the latest version of tensorflow in pycharm and it's different than colab, i dont wana change the tensorflow version, i want to see what alternative code do i have

Comment: in pycharm i have tensorflow 2.16.1and keras 3.1.0
in colab i have tensorflow 2.15.0 and keras 2.15.0

Comment: Ok, compare that to the versions you installed in the Google Collab instance. If they're different, fix the versions in PyCharm so that they're the same as in Collab.

Comment: i did it and still not working