# check is modules installed correctly

Tags: python, module, pydoc

I believe that I've just installed pip, nose, distribute and virtualenv. I wanted to check and in the terminal ran pydoc modules to see what was there - none of them appear. Am I missing something? Should those modules appear. Terminal output is below (Mac, Python 2.7).

To install these modules I first installed pip using `sudo easy_install pip`. Then, I did the following:

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install nose
pip install distribute
```

All seemed to "work" - the terminal downloaded some stuff and printed some output that I think implied that it worked (I cannot go back and copy/paste the output since I closed that terminal window and reopened, in the hope that my newly installed modules might appear)

How can I tell if I have successfully installed those modules? Have I?

```
My Name-MacBook:~ myname$ pydoc modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

2014-01-08 11:56:42.191 Python[3196:1107] Error loading /Developer/Library/Frameworks/InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/InterfaceBuilderKit:  dlopen(/Developer/Library/Frameworks/InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/InterfaceBuilderKit, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/DevToolsRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsRemoteClient
  Referenced from: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/InterfaceBuilderKit
  Reason: image not found
2014-01-08 11:56:42.531 Python[3196:1107] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7ff9d4354070 </System/Library/Frameworks/Message.framework> (not loaded)
AVFoundation        _TE                 dircache            pstats
AddressBook         _Win                dis                 pty
AppKit              __builtin__         distutils           pwd
AppleScriptKit      __future__          dl                  py2app
AppleScriptObjC     _abcoll             doctest             py_compile
Audio_mac           _ast                dumbdbm             pyclbr
Automator           _bisect             dummy_thread        pydoc
BaseHTTPServer      _builtinSuites      dummy_threading     pydoc_data
Bastion             _codecs             easy_install        pyexpat
CFNetwork           _codecs_cn          email               pylab
CFOpenDirectory     _codecs_hk          encodings           pytz
CGIHTTPServer       _codecs_iso2022     errno               quopri
Canvas              _codecs_jp          exceptions          random
Carbon              _codecs_kr          fcntl               re
Cocoa               _codecs_tw          filecmp             readline
CodeWarrior         _collections        fileinput           repr
Collaboration       _csv                findertools         resource
ColorPicker         _ctypes             fnmatch             rexec
ConfigParser        _ctypes_test        formatter           rfc822
Cookie              _curses             fpformat            rlcompleter
CoreData            _curses_panel       fractions           robotparser
CoreFoundation      _elementtree        ftplib              runpy
CoreGraphics        _functools          functools           sched
CoreLocation        _hashlib            future_builtins     scipy
CoreText            _heapq              gc                  select
Dialog              _hotshot            genericpath         sets
DictionaryServices  _io                 gensuitemodule      setuptools
DocXMLRPCServer     _json               gestalt             sgmllib
EasyDialogs         _locale             getopt              sha
ExceptionHandling   _lsprof             getpass             shelve
Explorer            _multibytecodec     gettext             shlex
FSEvents            _multiprocessing    glob                shutil
FileDialog          _osx_support        grp                 signal
Finder              _pyio               gzip                site
FixTk               _random             hashlib             smtpd
Foundation          _scproxy            heapq               smtpd2
FrameWork           _socket             hmac                smtplib
HTMLParser          _sqlite3            hotshot             sndhdr
IN                  _sre                htmlentitydefs      socket
InputMethodKit      _ssl                htmllib             sqlite3
InstallerPlugins    _strptime           httplib             sre
InstantMessage      _struct             ic                  sre_compile
InterfaceBuilderKit _symtable           icglue              sre_constants
JavaScriptCore      _sysconfigdata      icopen              sre_parse
LatentSemanticMapping _testcapi           idlelib             ssl
LaunchServices      _threading_local    ihooks              stat
MacOS               _tkinter            imageop             statvfs
Message             _warnings           imaplib             string
MimeWriter          _weakref            imghdr              stringold
MiniAEFrame         _weakrefset         imp                 stringprep
Nav                 abc                 importlib           strop
Netscape            aepack              imputil             struct
OSATerminology      aetools             inspect             subprocess
OpenDirectory       aetypes             io                  sunau
OpenSSL             aifc                itertools           sunaudio
PixMapWrapper       altgraph            json                symbol
PreferencePanes     antigravity         keyword             symtable
PubSub              anydbm              lib2to3             sys
PyObjCTools         applesingle         linecache           sysconfig
PyRSS2Gen           appletrawmain       locale              syslog
QTKit               appletrunner        logging             tabnanny
Quartz              argparse            macerrors           tarfile
Queue               argvemulator        macholib            telnetlib
ScreenSaver         array               macostools          tempfile
ScriptingBridge     ast                 macpath             terminalcommand
ScrolledText        asynchat            macresource         termios
SearchKit           asyncore            macurl2path         test
ServiceManagement   atexit              mailbox             textwrap
SimpleDialog        audiodev            mailcap             this
SimpleHTTPServer    audioop             markupbase          thread
SimpleXMLRPCServer  autoGIL             marshal             threading
SocketServer        base64              math                time
StdSuites           bdb                 matplotlib          timeit
StringIO            bdist_mpkg          md5                 tkColorChooser
SyncServices        bgenlocations       mhlib               tkCommonDialog
SystemConfiguration binascii            mimetools           tkFileDialog
SystemEvents        binhex              mimetypes           tkFont
Tix                 bisect              mimify              tkMessageBox
Tkconstants         bonjour             mmap                tkSimpleDialog
Tkdnd               bsddb               modulefinder        toaiff
Tkinter             bsddb185            modulegraph         token
UserDict            buildtools          mpl_toolkits        tokenize
UserList            bundlebuilder       multifile           trace
UserString          bz2                 multiprocessing     traceback
WebKit              cPickle             mutex               ttk
XgridFoundation     cProfile            netrc               tty
_AE                 cStringIO           new                 turtle
_AH                 calendar            nis                 twisted
_App                cfmfile             nntplib             types
_CF                 cgi                 ntpath              unicodedata
_CG                 cgitb               nturl2path          unittest
_CarbonEvt          chunk               numbers             urllib
_Cm                 cmath               numpy               urllib2
_Ctl                cmd                 objc                urlparse
_Dlg                code                opcode              user
_Drag               codecs              operator            uu
_Evt                codeop              optparse            uuid
_File               collections         os                  videoreader
_Fm                 colorsys            os2emxpath          warnings
_Folder             commands            parser              wave
_Help               compileall          pdb                 weakref
_IBCarbon           compiler            pickle              webbrowser
_Icn                contextlib          pickletools         whichdb
_LWPCookieJar       cookielib           pimp                wsgiref
_Launch             copy                pipes               xattr
_List               copy_reg            pkg_resources       xdrlib
_Menu               crypt               pkgutil             xml
_Mlte               csv                 platform            xmllib
_MozillaCookieJar   ctypes              plistlib            xmlrpclib
_OSA                curses              popen2              xxsubtype
_Qd                 datetime            poplib              zipfile
_Qdoffs             dateutil            posix               zipimport
_Qt                 dbhash              posixfile           zlib
_Res                dbm                 posixpath           zope
_Scrap              decimal             pprint              
_Snd                difflib             profile             

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose descriptions contain the word "spam".
```

Comment: did you try `import [modulename]` from a python interpreter prompt? That is the only way to tell, we aren't logged into your computer, you are though.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I have now since you added your comment. All seemed well for nose, virtualenv and pip, but distribute "No module named distribute". Also, since doing that I tried pydoc module again to see if I could see the modules but they do not appear

Comment: [`help('modules')`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used `pip list` in the shell which showed my modules.