# When a python module (cairo) is installed successfully but fails to import in python, what could be the issue?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pycharm, cairo

When a python module is installed successfully but fails to import in python (via PyCharm IDE), what could be the issue?  What checklist should I follow to diagnose the problem in this case and in the future when a module installs but later fails to import?

For this specific case, I installed a vector graphics module for Python called **cairo**.
http://cairographics.org/releases/pycairo-1.8.8.tar.gz

See the successful install below:

```
sudo python setup.py install
cairo >= 1.8.8 detected
creating pycairo.pc
creating src/config.h
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairo
copying build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cairo/_cairo.so -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairo
running install_data
creating /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/pycairo
copying src/pycairo.h -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/pycairo
copying pycairo.pc -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pkgconfig
running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycairo-1.8.8-py2.7.egg-info
```

Everything seemed to proceed smoothly, but later this module failed to import when called for in Python:  `ImportError: No module named cairo`.

One possibility is that it was installed in the wrong directory - `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.
Another possibility is that I should be somehow telling python the location of the module explicitly.  i.e.:  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairo`, based on the output of the install script found above.

It is quite odd, because cairo is present in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`, and I am able to import other libraries such as PIL found in the same directory.

[image]

Based on aIKID's suggestion, I tried using pip to get the installed packages.  From this, I got a long list, including a module called pycairo.  I tried importing both pycairo and cairo and still got an import error.  It's interesting that "cairo" is found in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairo`, but "pycairo" is found after a call of `pip.get_installed_distributions()`.  It seems that the distribution is called pycairo, and the module is called cairo.  import cairo should work, but either way both imports fail.

[image]

Based on Christopher's suggestion, I checked the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/` directory and did not find cairo.  By the same token, I did not find PIL (the python imaging library).  I am still able to import PIL, which is found in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`, together with cairo.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL, cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cairo
```

Comment: No, i think it's supposed to be like that. Have you restarted the shell?

Comment: does restart the shell mean start a new instance of python?   I restarted the pycharm IDE w/ no luck, and I started a new instance of oython in the terminal, no luck.

Comment: Do you have pip installed? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules)

Comment: what interpreter are you using in pycharm?

Comment: the import fails in terminal as well as pycharm.  i'm using python 2.7 in both.

Comment: aikid:   I used pip and got a long list of available modules via pip.get_installed_distributions.  In this list I found pycairo==1.8.8.  I tried both import cairo and import pycairo to no avail.  it's really odd.  maybe something specific to the cairo module?    interestingly, in the /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ path I see 'cairo', but using pip.get_installed_distributions I get pycairo==1.8.8.   It doesn't matter if I try importing pycairo or cairo ..... still doesn't work; must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can run python interactive mode and simply do the following steps to confirm your lib paths:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

As you can see, `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/` is the path in my system.

You might have multiple versions of python, but you can confirm which one you are using by doing this.

Comment: That's what I get too -- <module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>.  Still, import cairo directly after this fails with "ImportError: No module named cairo"

Comment: Check if cairo exists in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/

Comment: thanks!! getting closer - you're right, it doesn't exist there.  so what does this mean if it is found in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ but not in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ ?  This is the case for PIL the python imaging library, but I can still import PIL successfully.

Comment: Perhaps the installation script is not working properly for OS X.  A quick solution might be creating symbolic links in your path dir.

Comment: Otherwise you might write sys.path.insert(0, "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages") before import cairo, but your program will be less portable on other systems.

Comment: I had to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pkgconfig/ in the environment variables.  any idea why that worked?  feel free to add this to your answer and I will accept.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not for python.  Have you tried the tricks mentioned above?

Comment: I tried all of the above - adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pkgconfig/ to the environment variables in PyCharm was the only thing that worked.

Comment: I simply copy cario installed by waf to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib, then it works'