# Pythonic way to check if a package is installed or not

Tags: python, centos, redhat

Pythonic way to check list of packages installed in Centos/Redhat?

In a bash script, I'd do:

```
 rpm -qa | grep -w packagename
```

Comment: can do same in python using system command.

Comment: Is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Comment: rpm seems to have python bindings provided via `rpm-python`: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s03s04.html (That's what I found, haven't used it..)

Comment: The last time I tried to use the Python RPM API, I found almost no documentation for it.  (I see the link posted by @sebastian is a start.) It's not a simple API and reverse-engineering it would take some time.  It almost seems to be treated by Fedora/RH as an internal product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import sys
import rpm

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch( 'name', sys.argv[1] )
try :
    h = mi.next()
    print "%s-%s-%s" % (h['name'], h['version'], h['release'])
except StopIteration:
    print "Package not found"
```

1. TransactionSet() will open the RPM database
2. dbMatch with no paramters will set up a match iterator to go over the entire set of installed packages, you can call next on the match iterator to get the next entry, a header object that represents one package
3. dbMatch can also be used to query  specific packages, you need to pass the name of a tag, as well as the value for that tag that you are looking for:

   ```
   dbMatch('name','mysql')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen("rpm -qa | grep -w packagename", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = child.communicate()[0]
print output
```

using [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
import os
os.system("rpm -qa | grep -w packagename")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

present=0
notpresent=0
f3=open('INSTALLED.log','w')
f2=open('NOTINSTALLED.log','w')

f1=open('installed_packagelist.log','w')

var = os.popen("rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}\n]'").read()
f1.write(var)


lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('installed_packagelist.log')]

for index in range(len(lines)):
 contents = lines[index]
 test_str = "rpm -V " + contents
 var = os.system(test_str)
 if (var == 0):
  print contents + "file present"
  present = present +1
  f3.write(contents)

 else:
  print contents + "file not present"
  notpresent = notpresent + 1
  f2.write(contents)  

print present
print notpresent

f2.close()
f3.close()

f3=open('INSTALLED.log','r')
f2=open('NOTINSTALLED.log','r')


data=f3.read()
print data

print       "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

data=f2.read()
print data
```

Comment: Please read [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) topic. You should at least provide some description, not just some piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258124/498657 to work on Python 3.6.8, what did work for me was:

```
import sys
import rpm

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch( 'name', 'lsof' )

rpmhit=0
for h in mi:
    if h['name'] == 'lsof':
        rpmhit=1
        break

if rpmhit == 0:
    print('Error: Package lsof not installed. Install using: dnf install lsof')
    sys.exit(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6.12 to verify if package "pacemaker-cli" is installed I used:

```
import rpm

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch( 'name', 'pacemaker-cli' )

try :
    h = mi.__next__()
    print ("%s-%s-%s.%s" % (h['name'].decode(), h['version'].decode(), h['release'].decode(), h['arch'].decode()))

except StopIteration:
    print ("Package not found")
```