# I can't stop the deluged process on OSX

Tags: python, macos

I've been using deluged on my Linux PC (Debian) without any problems. Lately I've started to run it on my Mac mini (OSX Lion 10.7.4) and there are several issues:

1- After I start it up using

```
/Applications/Deluge.app/Contents/MacOS/deluged
```

it starts with several warning and/or error messages such as:

```
/Applications/Deluge.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python/twisted
/internet/_sslverify.py:184: UserWarning: You do not have the
service_identity module installed. Please install it from
<https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity>...
```

I've installed service_identity. [On the installed modules script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) it appears as:

```
'service-identity==14.0.0'
```

But still, the same warning message appears on startup.

2- More importantly, after several days sometimes after several hours of operation deluged seems to do excessive read/writes on the harddisk. To stop it from overworking the harddisk, I try to stop the deluged process using **kntrl-C** on the command line but most of the time it doesn't stop, particularly if it's been working for more than several hours. I have to stop it from GUI activity monitor of OSX using the **'force quit'**; it can't be stopped using the plain 'quit'. [Here's a screenshot where I try to stop it](http://i.hizliresim.com/ly567l.png)

Is there anything I can do to solve these problems? Thanks.

Comment: Is pip pointing to the same interpreter you are running the script with?

Comment: I can't correctly know that. I can check only

$ pip --version => pip 7.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

$ python --version => python 2.7.1
$ which python => /usr/bin/python

Also 
![ls /Applications/Deluge.app/Contents/Resources/lib/](http://i.hizliresim.com/ZVol4g.png)

Comment: Stackexchange didn't allow me to edit comment so last line was: 

$ ls /Applications/Deluge.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ returns: http://i.hizliresim.com/ZVol4g.png