# No module named nanguardmode

Tags: python, theano

I have a bug in my theano program leading to NaN values. The doc recommends using `nanguardmode` to track down the source of the problem.

When I copy/paste this line from the doc webpage:

```
from theano.compile.nanguardmode import NanGuardMode
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named nanguardmode
```

Can't find any sign of `nanguardmode` when I type:

```
help(theano.compile)
```

Any idea why `nanguardmode` is absent? How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Thanks for your replies.

Concerning my Theano version, I'm couldn't find how to check it. But I assume it is the latest: I installed it form the install webpage about about a month ago. I'm on Windows 64bit.

Concerning detect_nan hack: things just get weirder!

First: if I try to use:

```
post_func=theano.compile.monitormode.detect_nan
```

I get:

```
File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\monitormode.py", line 87, in detect_nan
if (not isinstance(numpy.random.RandomState, output[0]) and

NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Indeed, numpy was not imported in the monitormode module... Is that a known bug?

Second: if I try to use a copy/paste of detect_nan, the NaNs magically go away. Everything else remaining the same, without detect_nan in my theano function (that trains a model iteratively), I get NaNs at iteration 5:

```
epoch 1, valid 28.582677 %, train 27.723320 % 0.546633
epoch 2, valid 27.814961 %, train 25.681751 % 0.500522
epoch 3, valid 27.263780 %, train 24.262972 % 0.478799
epoch 4, valid 26.938976 %, train 23.209021 % 0.463017
epoch 5, valid 50.000000 %, train 50.000000 % nan
```

(the last figure is the cost value)

When I do add

```
mode=theano.compile.MonitorMode(post_func=detect_nan)
```

to the function, no NaNs appear up to at least iteration 100 (and probably more).

```
epoch 1, valid 28.582677 %, train 27.723320 % 0.546633
epoch 2, valid 27.814961 %, train 25.681751 % 0.500522
epoch 3, valid 27.263780 %, train 24.262972 % 0.478799
epoch 4, valid 26.938976 %, train 23.209021 % 0.463017
epoch 5, valid 26.289370 %, train 22.320902 % 0.450454
... etc ...
```

What's going on here???

Comment: What is your theano version?

Comment: dunno what happened but after restarting the console, everything is back in shape...

Comment: So you no longer need answers for the updated portion of your question? If so, perhaps you could add your own answer with what you found helped you?

Comment: Nothing really 'helped me' beside restarting the console. 
The bug was 'real' in a sense that it was reproducible before restarting the console. But after restarting, it seems gone for good. I assume the computer was in some strange internal state...

Comment: I guess the missing 

    import numpy

in monitormode.py should still be reported, but I don't know where / to whom...

Comment: To check a package version you can use `pip show yourPackageName` in command line. Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Answer (score 2):

`NanGuardMode` was moved to Theano's bleeding edge version (from PyLearn2) on May 1st. This was after the release of version 0.7 on March 26th so you'll need to [upgrade to the bleeding edge version](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions) from GitHub to use NanGuardMode.

Alternatively you could use the `detect_nan` sample found in the [debug FAQ](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-step-through-a-compiled-function):

```
import numpy

import theano

# This is the current suggested detect_nan implementation to
# show you how it work.  That way, you can modify it for your
# need.  If you want exactly this method, you can use
# ``theano.compile.monitormode.detect_nan`` that will always
# contain the current suggested version.

def detect_nan(i, node, fn):
    for output in fn.outputs:
        if (not isinstance(output[0], numpy.random.RandomState) and
            numpy.isnan(output[0]).any()):
            print '*** NaN detected ***'
            theano.printing.debugprint(node)
            print 'Inputs : %s' % [input[0] for input in fn.inputs]
            print 'Outputs: %s' % [output[0] for output in fn.outputs]
            break

x = theano.tensor.dscalar('x')
f = theano.function([x], [theano.tensor.log(x) * x],
                    mode=theano.compile.MonitorMode(
                        post_func=detect_nan))
```