# Unable to import an installed package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import, importerror, enthought

I use the Enthought Canopy environment with Python, v1.5.5. The Package Manager indicates I have beautifulsoup4 installed, v4.3.2-5. Yet all of the following fail, producing `Import Error: No module named xxxxxx`:

```
import beautifulsoup
import beautifulsoup4
import BeautifulSoup
```

[Listing installed packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) includes `..., 'beautifulsoup4==4.3.2', ...` in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what is there in the ["Quick Start" documentation paragraph](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```