# Python3 does not find modules installed by pip3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip

I'm having problems with python3. For some reason that I cannot figure out, the modules available in python3 are not the same as the ones installed via pip3.

Running `pip3 list` in a Terminal returns:

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
nltk (3.2.2)
numpy (1.12.0)
pandas (0.19.2)
pip (9.0.1)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
pytz (2016.10)
setuptools (25.2.0)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Running [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/2254210) to see what modules `python3` has available returns:

```
 ['cycler==0.10.0', 'matplotlib==1.5.3', 'nltk==3.2.1', 'numpy==1.11.2', 'pip==9.0.1', 'pyparsing==2.1.10', 'python-dateutil==2.6.0', 'pytz==2016.7', 'setuptools==18.2', 'six==1.10.0']
```

These two are not the same and I can't tell why. `nltk`, for example, has an older version. `pandas` is missing.

I've installed python via homebrew and I'm running scripts via Textmate2. However, I have the same problem when I run code in terminal, via `python3`. Both pip3 and python3 are installed in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
$ which python3 pip3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

And that's also the version python3 is using:

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'/usr/local/bin'
```

If someone could help me figure out why this is the case, and how I can fix it, I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Try the command "ls -l `which python3 pip3`" to see where the links are pointing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the first line of the `pip3` script.

The first line (starting with `#!` should point to the same executable as the symbolic link for python 3:

```
> head -n 1 /usr/local/bin/pip
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

> ls -ld /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  9 Dec 25 22:37 /usr/local/bin/python3@ -> python3.6
```

If this is not the case, deinstall `pip` and install it again with the correct Python version.

**EDIT**:

If you **really** want to make sure that you're using the the right Python with `pip`, then call it as a module like this:

```
python3.7 -m pip list
```

If you get the error `No module named pip`, then `pip` is not installed for this version of python.

Comment: You're right, pip pointed to an old install of python3 I didn't know I had. I [removed everything](http://superuser.com/a/276843/308345) and did a clean install via homebrew. Everything is working again now. Thanks!

Comment: had to change the path to ls -ld /usr/bin/python3

Comment: > head -n 1 /usr/local/bin/pip
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6

but 
> ls -ld /usr/local/bin/python3
ls: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory

what should I do?

Comment: @Michael You could for example add `usr/local/opt/python/bin` to your path, or create a `python3` symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/` pointing to `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran to this problem in Windows. first of all I uninstall the package using cmd command `pip3 uninstall moduleName`.
Then based on python documentation I run command `python -m pip install moduleName` and my problem solved!

Here is the documentation: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

Comment: The question was regarding the problem with the pip.