# Opencv will not import

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip, opencv3.0

I ran `pip3 install opencv-python==3.3.0.10`

but I am getting

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I know there are many ways to install `opencv` but this one seemed the most straightforward.

Comment: Are you sure your `pip3` is installing it for Python 3.6? I had a problem where `pip3` installed packages for 3.5 only

Comment: @collector how about this ```$ pip3.6 install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from opencv-python)```

Comment: Are you sure all the links are pointing to the right directories? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304140/python3-does-not-find-modules-installed-by-pip3

Comment: Check all pythons on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open a terminal and pip install cmake:

```
pip install cmake
```

2 - Download opencv repository from https://github.com/opencv/opencv

3 - On your terminal cd to the folder where you downloaded the opencv repository and compile it with cmake typing the following commands:

```
mkdir release

cd release

cmake -D CMAKE_BULD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON USE_V4L=ON WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON USE_GStreamer=ON ..

make

make install
```

Opencv is now correctly installed on your machine and you should be able to successfully import it in Python with no error.

Let me know if this solves the problem