# Why modules installed by pip3 can not be used python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

In new Ubuntu server, I run the following commands to install pip.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

But python3 can not find the installed modules. Does anybody know how to install pythons modules so that they can work properly?

```
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ pip3 install socks
Requirement already satisfied: socks in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0)
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socks'
```

Comment: you are probably looking for `/usr/local/bin/python3`, no?

Comment: The best way to handle environment is using venv for every application.

Comment: I don't have /usr/local/bin/python3. I used the default python3 to install pip. Should pip install it in /usr/bin. I don't understand why the installation instruction of pip is something that does not work.

Comment: ^^^ Seconded, you should use virtual environments, and you shouldn't mess with the system python to be safe

Comment: @user1424739 try to see if this answers your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304140/python3-does-not-find-modules-installed-by-pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304140/python3-does-not-find-modules-installed-by-pip3)

Comment: since you are using python installed through package manager i suggest to install pip using `sudo apt install python3-pip python3-venv`

Comment: No.  The link does not answer my question. I have no interested in debugging what is wrong. I just want to know what commands I need to run to make pip3 properly installed so that the packages can be used with python3.

Comment: @sahasrara62 How to uninstall the pip and modules installed in /usr/local?

Comment: @user1424739 on this i strongly suggest not to disturb that part now as it might cause your system  failure as some application might depend on it (saying it with experience), use a virtual env for the project that would be great, otherwise, if you want to use python only in system, i suggest you to install python3 and pip3 in known location and in ubuntu bash shell provide the path to that  python to execute, and run. again, strongly suggest , unless u really know how system python configured, don't touch `/usr/local/` python

Comment: @sahasrara62 It still doesn't work with `apt install python3-pip python3-venv`. $ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
$ pip3 install socks
Requirement already satisfied: socks in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0)

Comment: try if `python3.8` open python interpreter in the terminal, and see `socks` there, otherwise try open `python3` or `python3.7` in terminal to see which python are  installed, again suggesting it is better to use a virtualenv instead of going through this all troublesome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349800/11138259

Answer (score 0):

I turns out this pip3 installation command should be used.

```
pip3 install pysocks
```

Comment: Use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install pysocks` or `python3 -m pip install pysocks` instead. Guaranteed to install for the correct Python interpreter.