# Virtual Machine Setup and syncing project dependencies

Tags: python, linux, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Hi I am using vagrant to run a local linux environment on my windows OS.

The problem is, I am trying to run my python project on it but there are a whole lot of dependencies, including nltk, which takes a long time to download.

Other than manually re-downloading and installing all the dependencies onto the VM, is there a better way to sync my existing python libraries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the package on your host machine, share the folder where you have the download and run the install in the VM from the shared directory.

```
$ pip install mypackage --no-index --find-links file:///vagrant/share/package
```