# How I will know what pip packages need my python project and how to list what I already use in my project

Tags: python, pip

On my project located in a folder named `example` contains all the .py files of the project. Also my project uses some packages provided via pip, but when I need to upload to the common git repo for my coleagues in order to use it I need somwhow to "index" or to "list" the required packages that I installed via pip in order to download them.

In other words I am looking a similar functionality with node's `npm` or php's composer where there is the ability to save all the references for my dependencies so my coleagues to download them via either `npm install` or `composer install`. So I am asking how can I achieve similar functionality with pip?

## Edit 1:

I only have installed some pip packages how I will get the one I `import` into my source code?

I mean on my project's spurce i habe entries like:

```
import ^package_name^
from ^package_name^ import ^some_function_or_class^
```

How I will locate the pip packages I install by looking the import entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for in your _Edit 1_. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are requirements files.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

If you wanted to save all your current packages you could do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, but I wouldn't recommend it as this would add not only the packages your script needs, but also the requirements of your requirements and so on. For example:

```
$ pip freeze
no packages installed
$ pip install requests
$ pip freeze
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.5
requests==2.18.1
urllib3==1.21.1
```

So in this example only requests should be in your requirements files, but if you dump `pip freeze` you have some extra packages.

Your requirements file could look like this:

```
# This is the contests of requirements.txt
requests>=2.18.1,<3.0.0
```

And to install it you would simply have to do `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

---

If you start working on different projects with different requirements you will definitely need to know about [virtual environments](https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). It's a way to have different set of python interpreters and packages installed. Similar to how `npm` will install the packages in your current folder.