# ImportError: No module named kek.ccache

Tags: python, python-2.7

I really feel dumb asking this. but when am running MS14-068.py (https://github.com/bidord/pykek/blob/master/ms14-068.py) module in my kali with python version 2.7.13 i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ms14-068.py", line 17, in <module>
from kek.ccache import CCache, get_tgt_cred, kdc_rep2ccache
ImportError: No module named kek.ccache
```

How do i fix this? I dont know much about pythonh. I googled it for that module but couldn't find a way. Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Seems kek.ccache namespace were not found in your current directory

Comment: This previous SO question and answer may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
You need to install pykek, which is where ccache resides.
You can't run it if you don't have it. :)

https://github.com/bidord/pykek