# how can I see my installed libraries in python ?

Tags: python, libraries

I would like to have a list with my installed libraries in my python console. How can be that possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules)

Answer (score 3):

in command line: `pip list`

you can output as `pip freeze`

just typing `pip` in a command line will give you all the very handy pip commands and flags

Comment: If modules installed under root, sudo will be required to list files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use help command.just type help("modules") in python idle or console

```
help("modules")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

Will give you the list of all the installed packages.