# Through docker Image, how to list out only the dependencies specified in dockerfile and not the ones which are automatically installed?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a dockerfile which specified 12 ubuntu dependencies to install. I created a docker image and then spin up a container using that docker image. I just tried to list out the dependencies present in the docker image by **"apt list --installed"** (by using shell inside running container). I am able to see 409 dependencies which also include automatically installed dependencies. Is there any way by which I can list out only those 12 dependencies listed in docker file?

Comment: @VonC...Yeah...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your container shell, you should try to look for a log file mentioning the recent installed packages.

See "[Is it possible to get a list of most recently installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/a/17013/5470)"

For instance:

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: Thanks @Vonc, the link you shared lists out all the recently installed ubuntu dependencies. Is there any way to list out recently installed python dependencies too.

Comment: @SushilRaut Not sure, as python dependencies are installed through pip (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/6309)

Answer (score 0):

I would spin up an instance of the base image and list its packages, then diff that list from the one for your derived instance.