# Which packages are installed?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to `Python`.

I'm using `winpython3` and `winspyder3`. How can I check which packages, modules and plugins are installed?
I didn't find anything here.
Thanks for the answers... but....
@Vineeth Sai: I'm using winspyder3, I get these error:

```
Start of code
    pip freeze
    The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

     $ pip freeze

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.
See the Python documentation for more information on how to install packages:
        https://docs.python.org/3/installing/
End of Code
```

@ Rajeev Atmakuri:
With the Code of your link, I get following output:

```
Start of code:
runfile('D:/Python/packages_001.py', wdir='D:/Python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-a7b650970979>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Python/packages_001.py', wdir='D:/Python')

  File "C:\WPy-3662\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\WPy-3662\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Python/packages_001.py", line 9, in <module>
    installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()

AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'
End of code
```

at all:
if you know octave: with

```
start of code:
    pkg list
end of code
```

you get a complete list of the installed packages...

Comment: run `pip freeze` in your command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules)