# How do I see what Python modules are installed, and what version?

Tags: python

I'm currently running Python 3.7 and also working in Visual Code through Anaconda, thus I have 2 separate install locations for modules. How can I look and see what Python modules are installed and what their current versions are?

Is there a way to do this without looking in the `site-packages` library one-by-one?

For instance, I want to make sure pandas, pyinstaller, pyqt5, tkinter, and more are the both installed in each directory and both the same version.

*EDIT -* Not the same question as [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules), as pip 10 has been updated and the code provided in the answer no longer works.

Comment: try - pip list? you are using pipenv just check pipenv file inside your venv.

Comment: @DmitrySurin Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you need is the `pip list` command on your terminal

Comment: This solved it, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

It returns a list of the packages intalled on your machine with their version number !

Best

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules to do it without dependencies on pip.

Comment: Looks exactly similar to accepted answer in the above link in comment to question :P

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute `get_installed_distributions` https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli/issues/657