# How can I see all installed Python modules in Jupyter Lab (like pip freeze) with Python 3.7 or newer?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-lab

I'm looking for a way to **get a list** of **all installed/importable python modules** from a within a Jupyterlab notebook.

From the command line, I can get the list by running

```
py -3 -m pip freeze
```

(or)

```
pip freeze
```

In the Jupyterlab console, running pip freeze returns

```
The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip freeze

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.

See the Python documentation for more information on how to install packages:

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/
```

For older versions of pip, it was possible to import pip and get a list from within a notebook.

The command was

```
help('modules')
```

This now gives a warning and returns nothing.

```
c:\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
```

10 year old stackoverflow solutions like [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) also no longer work.

Is there a proper way of doing this (without using a subprocess hack or running pip as an external program like "!pip")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pip._internal.operations.freeze
_ = pip._internal.operations.freeze.get_installed_distributions()
print(sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in _])[:10])
['absl-py==0.7.1',
 'aiml==0.9.2',
 'aio-utils==0.0.1',
 'aiocache==0.10.1',
 'aiocontextvars==0.2.2',
 'aiocqhttp==0.6.7',
 'aiodns==2.0.0',
 'aiofiles==0.4.0',
 'aiohttp-proxy==0.1.1',
 'aiohttp==3.6.2']
```

This works in Win10 with Python 3.6 & 3.7 (ipython, pip.**version**: '20.0.1') at least. I took a look at the source code in Lib\site-packages\pip.

Comment: I'm trying to get the name that colab uses for a file in my Google Drive. So, it's not an installed file, unless this means also modules created by me.

Answer (score 16):

You may run following snippet to the result.

```
!pip list
```

Comment: Thanks, using "!" works like running pip as any external program. This does work, still I'm wondering if there's a better way to interact with pip. I'm updating the question to make that clearer.

Comment: If you are using a custom kernel based on a venv, this will execute pip on the main env packages right ?

Answer (score 6):

you can also try

```
!pip freeze
```

in your jupyter notebook. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

`%pip list`
instead of
`!pip list`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```py
help("modules")
```

....