# How to list the 3rd party projects (libraries, etc.) installed using pip in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8, python-packaging

Is there any Python script or Python code that can give me the list of **Python projects** (distribution packages: libraries, etc.) installed (with *pip*, for example) so that I can iterate over them in a loop?

It should be working in `python3.x`.

Comment: I found this answer, I think this is your question
Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of locally installed Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple and straightforward way to do this directly in Python's standard library. Use [*`importlib.metadata`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html).

For example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import importlib.metadata

for distribution in importlib.metadata.distributions():
    print(distribution.metadata['Name'], distribution.metadata['Version'])
```

This will work for *Python 3.8+*. For versions older than *3.8* I would recommend using [*`importlib-metadata`*](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) to get the exact same features.

Comment: Get more info in [Single-sourcing the package version](https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/#single-sourcing-the-version) point **5.**.

Answer (score 0):

The `pip list` command will give you a list of all packages and their versions installed:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ------------
ailment                       9.0.4663
alabaster                     0.7.12
angr                          9.0.4663
appdirs                       1.4.4
apsw                          3.33.0.post1
... more lines that I cut off
```

If you want to loop through this in python, then you can use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to capture the output then do a bit of string processing:

```py
import subprocess

packages = subprocess.check_output(["python3", "-m", "pip", "list"]).decode("utf8")

package_lines = map(str.split, packages.splitlines()[2:])

for package_name, version in package_lines:
    print(f"Package {package_name} has version {version}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pip freeze
```

on your terminal to list all the installed python modules.

If you want those modules as a list in your python program, you would use *pkg_resources* module

```
# Credit: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-list-installed-python-packages/
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
                                  for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that using the pip library in python:

```
try:
    from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError:  # in case pip version < 10.0
    from pip.operations import freeze
modules = list(freeze.freeze())
```

Now the modules variable is a list containing all the pip installed modules/packages.

here's just whats stored in modules for me when i ran it:

```
['altgraph==0.17', 'appdirs==1.4.4', 'argon2-cffi==20.1.0', 'async-generator==1.10', 'attrs==20.2.0', 'auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8', 'autopep8==1.5.4', 'backcall==0.2.0', 'beautifulsoup4==4.9.1', 'bleach==3.2.1', 'bottle==0.12.18', 'bottle-websocket==0.2.9', 'cachetools==4.1.1', 'certifi==2020.6.20', 'cffi==1.14.3', 'chardet==3.0.4', 'click==7.1.2', 'colorama==0.4.3', 'cryptography==3.2.1', 'cycler==0.10.0', 'decorator==4.4.2', 'defusedxml==0.6.0', 'distlib==0.3.1', 'docopt==0.6.2', 'Eel==0.12.4', 'entrypoints==0.3', 'et-xmlfile==1.0.1', and so on.....]
```

I have cut it short as there is alot for me.

Comment: _pip_ is not meant to be used as a library (see [here for details](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id9)). This is not a good recommendation. There are better ways to do this. using [_`importlib.metadata`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) is the current best recommendation.