# Installed module causes 'ModuleNotFoundError' when executing script from Python. How can I use installed modules in my scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, subprocess

We develop using the django framework.
When using subProcess.run() to run a python file, a pip installed module is causing a 'ModuleNotFoundError'.
Is the module not loaded in the file executed by subProcess.run? Also, how do I use the module?
The development environment is built on AmazonLinux2 within docker.

・Process for calling Python files

```
# No error occurs in this file.
import yaml

script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "script.py")
subprocess.run(
    [script, args1, args2],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

・Python file to be called

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# os is loaded
import os 

import yaml

def main() {
~~~~~~~~
}
```

・Error Description

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

・install

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules?rq=2) and also check what directory you are running your pip from

Comment: "When using subProcess.run() to run a python file, a pip installed module is causing a 'ModuleNotFoundError'" - I see that you don't have an issue with the `import` from the main script. **Which Python executable is being used** to run the main script, and for the `subprocess.run` one? **How did you determine this?** Please figure out these answers, and then see the linked duplicate in order to understand the problem. What matters here is which Python installation is used to run each piece of code, and whether `pyyaml` has been installed **for that Python installation**.