# How do I get a list of function instances for a python source file?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have a file called `example.py` with the following content:

```
def func_one(a):
    return 1

def func_two(b):
    return 2

def func_three(b):
    return 3
```

How would I get a list of function instances for that file? I have tried playing with the `compiler`,`parser` and `ast` modules but I can't really figure it out. It might be a lot easier than that, but it's slightly out of my depth.

EDIT: To be clear I don't want to import the functions.

Comment: Could you explain what "func instances" means here?

Comment: Is it OK to import the module?

Comment: Tkae a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module

Comment: nah i dont want to import it. i just want access to the function itself.

Comment: Without actually importing the module, the problem is much harder (and you'll miss things like import-time actions that populate the module's namespace without using the `def` keyword, unless you implement your own Python language...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import example
>>> inspect.getmembers(example, inspect.isroutine)
[('func_one', <function func_one at 0x0238CBB0>), ('func_three', <functi
three at 0x0240ADB0>), ('func_two', <function func_two at 0x0240ADF0>)]
```

Comment: yeah i don't want to import it though.

Comment: that's close i think. i want to do that without actually importing it

Comment: How do you wanna do it then? I mean at least the file will be imported if not the functions. What is your use case?

Comment: well i guess i could import them, but i don't want the functions to be callable from the interpreter and pollute the local namespace.

Comment: local namespace will only have the name of the module you imported. Not the functions which reside in it. The functions need to be qualified with the module name still.

Comment: ah you're right. sorry i was slightly confused but i understand now. thanks this one will work! :)

Comment: ... If you don't want the functions to be usable, then why do you care what they are?

Comment: i am inspecting them for something but i do not want to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir). This return the list of names in the current local scope. Although this might return more than function names.

```
>>> import utils
>>> utils.__name__
'utils'
>>> dir(utils)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'human_number', 'islice', 'math', 'prime_factors', 'primes_sieve', 'primes_sieve1', 'proper_divisors', 'pyth_triplet', 'square_of_sum', 'sum_of_nums', 'sum_of_squares', 'test', 'triangle_nums', 'window']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to import into the namespace like this:

```
import examples
print dir(examples)

['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', 
'__package__', 'func_one', 'func_three', 'func_two'] #OUTPUT
```

You could `open` and `read` the file, doing a search for any `def`s and append those to a list, thus returning all function, and method definition names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use globals() function, it is return a dict with all global environment where you can find you functions.
Example:

```
d = globals().copy()
l = []
[l.append(k) for k in d if k.startswith('func')]
```