# How to locate a function in a Python module tree?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and am trying to import the function `group_by` into the interpreter, but I can't seem to find it. Is there an easy way to search the module tree to see where this function lives?

Of course I've tried `from sqlalchemy import + tab` and searching manually, but at each tree level there are too many options to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to step outside the interpreter and just [search the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/search.html?q=group_by&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

---

Meanwhile, it looks to me like there *is* no such function to import. There are `group_by` *methods* on `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` and `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.[Compound]Select[Base]` objects.

---

But if you really want to recursively walk through all the modules in a package looking for a name, here's how you'd do it:

```
import inspect

def find_name(package, name):
    if hasattr(package, name):
        yield package
    for modulename, submodule in inspect.getmembers(package, inspect.ismodule):
        yield from find_name(submodule, name)
```

For Python 3.2 or earlier, you need to replace the `yield from` with a loop:

```
for modulename, submodule in inspect.getmembers(package, inspect.ismodule):
    for result in find_name(submodule, name):
        yield result
```

And if you just want the first result, instead of all results, you can just `return` instead of `yield`ing:

```
def find_name(package, name):
    if hasattr(package, name):
        return package
    for modulename, submodule in inspect.getmembers(package, inspect.ismodule):
        result = find_name(submodule, name)
        if result:
            return result
```

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn I tried statements using it as a method and it said there was no such function. This is good to know, but I'd still like an answer to the module-searching question.

Comment: Is it possible that you tried using it on the wrong kind of object?

Answer (score 0):

try printing `SQLAlchemy.__all__` which will return you a list of all functions in that module which are publicly available.

Comment: Right, this is almost exactly the same as `from sqlalchemy import + tab`, it just leaves out submodules.

Comment: there is a thread with same kind of topic [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module]