# Access to vtkShader2 from python

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opengl, vtk

**Background:** I am using VTK 6.1 with Python 2.7 and want to define my own OpenGL shaders. In VTK 6 onwards the [way to do this has changed](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Proposal-deprecating-Cg-GLSL-XML-shader-framework-td5593259.html), and it should now be done using vtkShader2 rather than XML files. VTK provides wrappers for most of the underlying functionality of the C++ code using a semi-automated process which is documented [here](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Wrapping/Python/README_WRAP.txt).

**My problem:** is it possible to access vtkShader2 from Python?

**Tried so far:**

- I haven't found anything on the [online documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkShader2.html) for the Shader2 class
- vtkShader2 doesn't seem to exist when exploring the module using [pydoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module)
- A [relevant post](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2012-October/076879.html) on the official vtk users mailing list was asked in 2012 but hasn't been answered...
- No mention of shader issues on the official [Python Wrapping FAQ](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Python_Wrapping_FAQ) (though the page seems targeted at VTK pre-5.6)

Any suggestions would be very welcome. If vtkShader2 can be accessed, then that would be great! If it can't be accessed, then it would be useful to know so that I (and others) can work around it...