# Python won't identify 'imread' function

Tags: python, image, ubuntu

I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu and I was experimenting with images before beginning an assignment for my algorithms class. I have downloaded numpy, scipy and skimage packages and I keep getting the error that 'imread' 'title' and these inbuilt functions are undefined. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
   from pylab import *
   from skimage import img_as_float

   img = imread(‘someimage.png’)
   img = img_as_float(img)
   w, h = img.shape[:2]
   R = img[:,:,0]
   G = img[:,:,1]
   B = img[:,:,2]
   figure()
   gray()
   subplot(1,4,1); imshow(img); title(“RGB”)
   subplot(1,4,2); imshow(R); title(“Red”)
   subplot(1,4,3); imshow(G); title(“Green”)
   subplot(1,4,4); imshow(B); title(“Blue”)
   show()
```

Comment: I think that you should install Python Imaging Library (PIL). Check :: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: I tried downloading that using sudo pip install PIL.
Says no distributions found.

Comment: Tried sudo apt-get install python-imaging.
Its already there.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding:

```
from skimage.io import imread
```

to your imports.

Comment: Tried that. Still comes up with undefined names error.

Comment: @AveeshaSharma: If you tried this obvious thing, then why didn't you say that in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry. Pylab imports functions from numpy, scipy and skimage. So I didn't realize I had to explicitly mention from skimage.io import imread. 
By tried I meant, I tried it after reading your post. Didn't work.

Comment: @AveeshaSharma: Could you show the full traceback that you get to to the code in your question? Also, could you import pylab using `import pylab` and then do `pylab.__file__`? I'm wondering whether you have some other file named `pylab.py` that's being picked up first, and `pylab.__file__` should show which pylab file is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the imread function imported from? You can easily see all functions within an imported library. See- allhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module

If you are looking for SciPy's imread, you must do it along these lines...

```
from scipy.misc import imread
...
img = imread(‘someimage.png’)
```

or

```
from scipy import misc
...
img = misc.imread('someimage.png')
```

or

```
import scipy
... 
img = scipy.misc.imread(‘someimage.png’)
```

Python does not inherently know what the title function or imread functions/methods are without having it spelled out explicitly. Importing requires you import each function/class/library etc with respect to scope. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Also - first comment is correct. You will need PIL installed to use the imread function.

Comment: I tried doing that! from scipy.misc import imread. Still won't work.

Comment: What won't work? Does imread function show up as undefined or some other function? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Yes. They get showed up as undefined names. imread title imshow subplot.

Comment: @IanPrice Everything you've said is generally true, but `pylab` is a bit of an exception. Pylab imports a whole bunch of functions from numpy, scipy and matplotlib to try and resemble MATLAB. Not necessarily good Python practice, but using Pylab *should* mean that the functions OP is using show up in the global namespace.

Comment: @Marius Interesting... have used SciPy quite a bit but never Pylab. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

if your facing problem while reading image try this

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
im = imread(image.png)
```