# Why doesn't this package work in python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, package, compatibility

I'm curious, for a small custom python package.

If I run the python file that imports and uses function from the package in python2, everything works fine. If I run the file in python3 though it fails importing functions from the package.

```
    from cust_package import this_function
ImportError: cannon import name 'this_function'
```

The functions in the package seem to be python3 compatible, and I used futurize on them just in case. Is the issue to do with some sort of labeling of the package/python version? The package is tiny, 2 .py files of ~8 functions each.

Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of this behavior please?

Comment: @LaraChicharo I updated the question to be about the real issue, including error message. The dir() issue was just a symptom of the actual problem. Thank you for pushing me to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> The default **dir()** mechanism behaves differently with different types
>   of objects, as it attempts to produce the most **relevant**, rather than
>   complete, information.

[Dir documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

There are available questions if you want all the available functions.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module)

Comment: You're correct, and I've updated the question to reflect the real issue, as the dir() complication is really just a symptom of the issue. I'm sorry for failing to clarify until now.