# Copy a python file structure

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to copy the file structure of a python file. In PyCharm, I can view the structure using `Command` + `F12`.

[image]

Is there a way to copy the text of the structure?

Comment: Can you disambiguate "copy" in this context?

Comment: You can use a Python interpreter to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/139198/2214933 I don't know if PyCharm has a GUI method to do the same thing.

Comment: By "copy" I mean get the structure in text form. The `dir()` function in the linked answer is interesting. Can it be run to not show inherited methods?

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Conversation`'s first method (`__init__()`), then `Shift-click` on method `responses_length()`, right mouse click, then `Copy` copies it into your clipboard as text. That gives you all methods in your class.