# How to get a list of attributes, methods with their classes for given python module?

Tags: python

How can we query a python module for its structured content outline (blueprint table of contents)? Kindly share if there is any method, module or trick by when we can analyze and query a python module for information like following in one go?

- classes available in modules (with inheritance info if any)
- attributes available per class
- methods provided by each class in the module

I came across python `__dict__` and `dir()` which in general provides the information BUT doesn't clearly distinguish between the methods and class attributes.

Wondering if there is a utility, way to have a **clean, readable and pythonic style** list of all classes with their attributes and methods for any given python module?

Additional information like `local`, `global` for attributes (if available) might also be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the inspect module

Comment: same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module

Comment: We seek information like attributes (if possible `local`, `global`), available methods, classes and inheritance links here.