# Import module than name functions in module?

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import

I have a ipynb file called function_list that has this code

```
'''
Hello, This is autoprinted on importing this module for additional information enter 
help(function_list)
'''
def add(a,b):
    ''' prints addition'''
    print(a +b)
def sub(c,d):
    ''' prints subtraction'''
    print(d - c)
def state(string):
    ''' prints a string'''
    print(string)
!jupyter nbconvert --to script function_list.ipynb
```

When I import this with

```
from function_list import *
```

in another file it works, but if I type help(function_list) it throws the error

error: name 'function_list' is not defined. If I import the functions with just

```
import function_list
```

it does not import all the functions.

both dir and help didn't work.

I used this link.

[How to list all functions in a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module)

Comment: using `import function_list` works fine for me

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, if I do that help(function_list) and dir(function_list) both work, BUT you can't call all the functions when you import that way. You have to use both import function_list and from function_list import * to acquire the functions and import the file name. I was trying to state one statement and gets the whole file.

Comment: You can use `import function_list` and then use `function_list.YOUR_Method` to call. Ex: `function_list.add(1,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `help` on module using below syntax

**Ex:**

```
import function_list 
print(help(function_list ))
```

And to call the function inside use

```
function_list.add(1,3)    #-->4
function_list.sub(1,3)    #-->2
function_list.state("Hello")   #-->Hello
```

Comment: Thank you this was a good work around. I forgot about the function_list.function functionality in python!

Comment: The tick symbol next to answer