# How can I see all the functions in "nt"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see the code `from nt import` in `os.py`.

I want to see all those functions "with detailed code" in "nt".

For example `mkdir()` is one of the functions in `nt`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at dir()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all functions in a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module)

Comment: How can I saw the detail code of mkdir() in nt ?

Answer (score 3):

the `nt` module seems to be a bit of a historical artifact, it's basically been merged into [`posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/posixmodule.c).  it should instead be imported via the [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/posix.html) for a very long time (i.e. [before Python 2.0](https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/module-posix.html)).

most of the functions there are native C code, so you'll need to to be relatively proficient in C to be able to understand what's going on.  the [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) and maybe the [Argument Clinic How-To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) sections in the docs have lots of relevant material

the actual C code behind those methods are in [`posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0fcdd8d6d67f57733203fc79e6a07a89b924a390/Modules/posixmodule.c#L3915) but its [header file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0fcdd8d6d67f57733203fc79e6a07a89b924a390/Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h#L1081) also does some parameter marshalling.  native methods are defined by `PyMethodDef` structures, but these can be somewhat obscured in older code bases like CPython

Answer (score 1):

`nt` is an OS-specific module, so you really shouldn't be using that. It may only be available on Windows.

Note that `os` does actually import the right module into its own namespace (this is what `from nt import *` does in its code when it runs on Windows, whereas it will do `from posix import *` instead if it runs on Mac OS or Linux).

Therefore, you should actually just look at all the functions of `os`.

Starting Python in interactive mode on the command line you can do this:

```
import os
help(os)
```

If you just want to see all names `os` has to offer, you can do:

```
import os
print(dir(os))
```

If you specifically need help on `mkdir`, you can also ask for help on this particular function:

```
import os
help(os.mkdir)
```

Comment: Well, you don't need to (and you shouldn't) look into the `nt` module. Just look into `os.mkdir`. Or are you asking for the source code of `mkdir()`?

Comment: I just want to see the source code of nt module or where it is.
I'm wonder why I can easily saw the source code of os.py module, but I can't even find the nt module in any directory.

Comment: As Sam Mason explained in his answer, the `nt` module doesn't exist anymore in modern Python. Instead it gets the `mkdir` function from the `posix` module. But even if the `nt` module existed, it would not be Python code. It would have been written in C and compiled to machine code and Python would make direct use of that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the IDEs support this options.

---

Without the need to install anything - you can use `ipython` for that.

Just start to write your requested module, `.` and then press `tab`, and the `ipython` will display all the documented options.
[image: os options]

You can find `ipython.exe` at `C:\[your-python]\scripts\ipython.exe`.

I'll advice to add this folder to your `environment PATH`.

Comment: This isn't really the answer to OP's question.

Comment: When I search for nt in python Lib,I just saw activate.bat, Activate.ps1, deactivate.bat, python.exe, pythonw.exe in nt directory, and I can't find any function in these 5 files. Can you say more detail how to use ipython to see the functions with detail code in nt ? thanks

Comment: As I mentioned - go to the `scripts` folder (where your python in installed) and then look for `ipython.exe`. If you've installed your python in the last couple of years - this plugin is included.
Then - check out the instructions I wrote on the answers above.

Comment: But using ipython I can just saw the functions.
I want to see the source code of the nt module.