# List imported names after import *

Tags: python, module, namespaces, python-import

Let's say I run this command:

`from pyspark.sql.types import *`

How can I check all the names that have been imported into my namespace? For instance, `IntegerType()` is now available, but is there a programmatic way of seeing all the names that have been imported with the *?

Note that I am not just looking for functions, but all names (including attributes) etc.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to say `dir(pyspark.seq.types)`. Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module

Comment: Do you mean `pyspark.sql.types`? It seems to work, but is this an exhaustive list?

Comment: You can compare a list of available names and compare it before and after the import. But just don't use starred imports like this to begin with.

Comment: Why are you asking? All of the types will be imported. Are you missing something? Do you have an error?