# Inside pdb, anyway to break on every python funciton like gdb rbreak filename:*?

Tags: python, gdb, pdb

Is there any way to insert pdb breakpoint on all functions inside a python file like gdb?

```
$  python3 -m pdb  gen_graph.py /vagrant/gdb.log
> /home/vagrant/dwnlds/gdb_graphs/gen_graph.py(11)<module>()
-> import os
(Pdb) rbreak ?
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(Pdb) b gen_graph.py:*
*** Bad lineno: *
(Pdb) b gen_graph.py:.
*** Bad lineno: .
(Pdb) b gen_graph.py:all
*** Bad lineno: all
(Pdb)
```

Or, is there anyway to list all function names (symbols) within a python file name?

Comment: To list functions, one can use `import ast `- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31005891/1755108