# Is there a way to iterate over modules installed with a package?

Tags: python-3.x, package, iteration

Say I've imported a package by doing `import package`. In each of the modules within this package, there is a function called "func". Is there a way to iterate over the modules that were imported with this package, calling the function for each module?

Something along the lines of this pseudocode:

```
import package

for module in package:
    module.func()
```

EDIT: solution

```
import inspect
import package

for name, module in inspect.getmembers(package, predicate=inspect.ismodule):
    module.func()
```

Now it is also required that you filter out the built in modules that are returned and don't contain func implementations, but that is a separate problem altogether.

Comment: You could use this in a for loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran it without a for loop. However if you want to inspect multiple packages at once you´d have to loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import inspect

inspect.getmembers(pd, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
```

output (truncated):

```
[('array', <function pandas.core.construction.array>),
 ('bdate_range', <function pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.bdate_range>),
 ('concat', <function pandas.core.reshape.concat.concat>),
 ('crosstab', <function pandas.core.reshape.pivot.crosstab>),
 ('cut', <function pandas.core.reshape.tile.cut>),
 ('date_range', <function pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.date_range>),
 ('eval', <function pandas.core.computation.eval.eval>),
 ('factorize', <function pandas.core.algorithms.factorize>),
 ('get_dummies', <function pandas.core.reshape.reshape.get_dummies>),
 ('infer_freq', <function pandas.tseries.frequencies.infer_freq>),
 ('interval_range', <function pandas.core.indexes.interval.interval_range>),
 ('isna', <function pandas.core.dtypes.missing.isna>),
 ('isnull', <function pandas.core.dtypes.missing.isna>),
 ('json_normalize', <function pandas.io.json._normalize._json_normalize>),
 ('lreshape', <function pandas.core.reshape.melt.lreshape>),
 ('melt', <function pandas.core.reshape.melt.melt>),
 ('merge', <function pandas.core.reshape.merge.merge>),
 ('merge_asof', <function pandas.core.reshape.merge.merge_asof>),
```