# Python: Run all functions in all python scripts in a folder dynamically

Tags: python, function

```
main_folder/
  __init__.py
  sub_folder1/
    __init__.py
    run_all_functions.py
  sub_folder2/
    __init__.py
    script1.py
    script2.py
    script3.py
```

script1.py

```
def something():
 ....
def something2():
 ....
```

script2.py

```
def example():
 ....
def example2():
 ....
```

script3.py

```
def example3():
 ....
```

Would like to check if there are ways that i can run all the functions in different scripts in folder2 and consolidate them in run_all_functions.py in folder1 dynamically. I might add more scripts with functions in folder 2 in the near future.

Comment: If the files define a module you could use `inspect` to load all the methods declared for each module. Then you only have to repeat the process through all the files. This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module

Comment: You could use exec, ie. open the .py files one by one and run exec on the text, like: `with open(filename, 'r') as file: exec(file.read())`

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you add a `run_all()` entry-point function to each `.py` file in a directory with your scripts, you could load all these file and call their respective `run_all()` functions.

Here is a little demonstration, adjust `DIR`.

```
import importlib.util
import pathlib

DIR = '/tmp/test'

for pyfile in pathlib.Path(DIR).glob('*.py'): # or perhaps 'script*.py'
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(f"{__name__}.imported_{pyfile.stem}" , pyfile)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    module.run_all()
```

Without a per module `run_all()`, you must use some kind of introspection to find all functions to be run.