# Match All Methods between two Python Sub-Modules

Tags: python

I have a customized module with following hierarchy:

```sh
module
  __init__.py
  kernel1
    __init__.py
    alg1.py
    alg2.py
  kernel2
    __init__.py
    alg1.py
    alg2.py
```

Here, `kernel1` and `kernel2` should implement exactly the same series of algorithms but using different bottom libraries.

I am wondering if there is a way that I can ensure every method defined in `kernel1` has a counterpart in `kernel2`, and vice versa.
For example, if there is a function `f_kernel1` defined in `kernel1` (either `alg1.py` or `alg2.py`), it should have a function `f_kernel2` defined in `kernel2` (either `alg1.py` or `alg2.py`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all functions in a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module) Once you know the functions in either module, checking that one set contains another is trivial

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible solutions is to define `kernel1` and `kernel2` as classes that contain functions (or wrappers to your implemented functions), and inherit from a common abstract base class.

This way the base class defines an empty implementation for the common functions, and each of the derived classes need to implement them (and this is enforced in several python IDEs)

Abstract classes can be defined with `abc` module.

for example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class KernelBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def func1(self):
        pass

class Kernel1(KernelBase):
    def func1(self):
        ...

class Kernel1(KernelBase):
    def func2(self):
        ...
```