# Search for function in given Python module

Tags: python

For example I remember that I need `train_test_split` function from sklearn module, but I don't remember I need to use `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` for import, I've tried to use `help()` in interactive mode with no results for `train_test_split` string:

```
import sklearn
help() # then type 'train_test_split' in interactive mode
```

do I need load each submodule and search pattern there ?

Comment: I use PyCharm which suggests matches.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can Google `train_test_split` until unless you are asking generally How to search a function in a module: [Maybe this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module)

In that case you can use

```
dir(sklearn)
help(sklearn)

from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, isclass
    
getmembers(sklearn, isfunction)
```