# Loop over all function in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So let's say I have a file like:

```py
#foo.py

def bar_one(a):
  return a + 1 

def bar_two(a):
  return a + 2 

...

def bar_n(a):
  return a + n
```

but I want to test this by check that the return type of all the functions are of type int.

So what I would like to do is somthing like this:

```py
# test_foo.py

import foo 

def test_foo():
  for func in foo:
    assert isinstance(func(1), int)
```

is there a way of doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all functions in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-module)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi almost the same thing but not really the same. There are similarities defiantly, but I would say that the answers here answers more specifically about how to access the function more than just listing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module has a attribute `__dict__`, which is a dictionary containing all objects in the module, so you can get all callable objects by using `filter` and `callable` (If you require that the object must be a function object, you can use `inspect.isfunction`):

```
import foo

for func in filter(callable, foo.__dict__.values()):   # Or use vars(foo) to obtain __dict__ implicitly
    assert isinstance(func(1), int)
```

To filter functions from other modules, you can judge the module name of the object:

```
for val in foo.__dict__.values():
    if callable(val) and val.__module__ == foo.__name__:
        assert isinstance(val(1), int)
```

Comment: This worked! However, be aware that this would include other stuff if `foo.py` imports some class or other function they to are included. Just so others knows. But this did solve the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @AxelG I added a new solution to this hidden danger.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `dir` function to have a list of all attributes and methods of a module and then call them with `foo[function_name]()`

Or use the `getmembers` function and filter the resulting list for functions with `isfunction` that gives a list of functions that you can call directly

Comment: What is `getmembers`?